# What are the mechanics of short string optimization in libc++?

Tags: c++, string, optimization, std, libc++

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10319672/1805388) gives a nice high-level overview of short string optimization (SSO). However, I would like to know in more detail how it works in practice, specifically in the libc++ implementation:

- How short does the string have to be in order to qualify for SSO?
  Does this depend on the target architecture?
- How does the implementation distinguish between short and long
  strings when accessing the string data? Is it as simple as `m_size <= 16` or is it a flag that is part of some other member variable? (I
  imagine that `m_size` or part of it might also be used to store
  string data).

I asked this question specifically for libc++ because I know that it uses SSO, this is even mentioned on the [libc++ home page](http://libcxx.llvm.org/).

Here are some observations after looking at [the source](http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/libcxx/trunk/include/string):

libc++ can be compiled with two slightly different memory layouts for the string class, this is governed by the `_LIBCPP_ALTERNATE_STRING_LAYOUT` flag. Both of the layouts also distinguish between little-endian and big-endian machines which leaves us with a total of 4 different variants. I will assume the "normal" layout and little-endian in what follows.

Assuming further that `size_type` is 4 bytes and that `value_type` is 1 byte, this is what the first 4 bytes of a string would look like in memory:

```
// short string: (s)ize and 3 bytes of char (d)ata
sssssss0;dddddddd;dddddddd;dddddddd
       ^- is_long = 0

// long string: (c)apacity
ccccccc1;cccccccc;cccccccc;cccccccc
       ^- is_long = 1
```

Since the size of the short string is in the upper 7 bits, it needs to be shifted when accessing it:

```
size_type __get_short_size() const {
    return __r_.first().__s.__size_ >> 1;
}
```

Similarly, the getter and setter for the capacity of a long string uses `__long_mask` to work around the `is_long` bit.

I am still looking for an answer to my first question, i.e. what value would `__min_cap`, the capacity of short strings, take for different architectures?

**Other standard library implementations**

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28003328/1805388) gives a nice overview of `std::string` memory layouts in other standard library implementations.

Comment: libc++ being open-source, you can find its `string` header [here](http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/libcxx/trunk/include/string), I am checking it out at the moment :)

Comment: You might be interested in [Small String Optimization and Move Operations](http://john-ahlgren.blogspot.co.at/2012/03/small-string-optimization-and-move.html)

Comment: @Matthieu M.: I had seen that before, unfortunately it's a very large file, thanks for the help in checking it out.

Comment: @Ali: I have stumbled over this in googling around. However, this blog post explicitly says that it is only an illustration of SSO and not a highly optimized variant that would be used in practice.

Answer (score 153, accepted):

The libc++ `basic_string` is designed to have a `sizeof` 3 words on all architectures, where `sizeof(word) == sizeof(void*)`.  You have correctly dissected the long/short flag, and the size field in the short form.

> what value would __min_cap, the capacity of short strings, take for different architectures?

In the short form, there are 3 words to work with:

- 1 bit goes to the long/short flag.
- 7 bits goes to the size.
- Assuming `char`, 1 byte goes to the trailing null (libc++ will always store a trailing null behind the data).

This leaves 3 words minus 2 bytes to store a short string (i.e. largest `capacity()` without an allocation).

On a 32 bit machine, 10 chars will fit in the short string.  sizeof(string) is 12.

On a 64 bit machine, 22 chars will fit in the short string.  sizeof(string) is 24.

A major design goal was to minimize `sizeof(string)`, while making the internal buffer as large as possible.  The rationale is to speed move construction and move assignment.  The larger the `sizeof`, the more words you have to move during a move construction or move assignment.

The long form needs a minimum of 3 words to store the data pointer, size and capacity.  Therefore I restricted the short form to those same 3 words.  It has been suggested that a 4 word sizeof might have better performance.  I have not tested that design choice.

**_LIBCPP_ABI_ALTERNATE_STRING_LAYOUT**

There is a configuration flag called `_LIBCPP_ABI_ALTERNATE_STRING_LAYOUT` which rearranges the data members such that the "long layout" changes from:

```
struct __long
{
    size_type __cap_;
    size_type __size_;
    pointer   __data_;
};
```

to:

```
struct __long
{
    pointer   __data_;
    size_type __size_;
    size_type __cap_;
};
```

The motivation for this change is the belief that putting `__data_` first will have some performance advantages due to better alignment.  An attempt was made to measure the performance advantages, and it was difficult to measure.  It won't make the performance worse, and it may make it slightly better.

The flag should be used with care.  It is a different ABI, and if accidentally mixed with a libc++ `std::string` compiled with a different setting of `_LIBCPP_ABI_ALTERNATE_STRING_LAYOUT` will create run time errors.

I recommend this flag only be changed by a vendor of libc++.

Comment: Not sure if there is license compatibility between libc++ and Facebook Folly, but the FBstring manages to store an extra char (i.e. 23) by changing size to *remaining capacity*, so that it can do double duty as null terminator for a short string of 23 chars.

Comment: @TemplateRex:  That is clever.  However if libc++ adopts it would require libc++ to give up one other characteristic that I like about its std::string:  A default constructed `string` is all 0 bits.  That makes default construction super efficient.  And if you're willing to bend the rules, sometimes even free.  E.g. you could `calloc` memory and just declare it to be full of default constructed strings.

Comment: Ah, 0-init is nice indeed! BTW, FBstring has 2 flag bits, indicating short, intermediate and large strings. It uses the SSO for strings up to 23 chars, and then uses a malloc-ed memory region for strings up to 254 chars and beyond that they do COW (no longer legal in C++11, I know).

Comment: Why can't size and capacity be stored in `int`s so that the class can be packed to only 16 bytes on 64-bit architectures?

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc:  I wanted to allow strings greater than 2Gb on 64-bit.  The cost is admittedly a greater `sizeof`.  But at the same time the internal buffer for `char` goes from 14 to 22, which is a pretty good benefit.

Comment: @HowardHinnant: Thanks! Don't you also get an extra byte out of this new layout, because the terminal null can now double as the short flag?

Comment: @KerrekSB:  That sounds like a good idea, but to the best of my knowledge, has not been implemented.  At least I didn't do it when I added `_LIBCPP_ABI_ALTERNATE_STRING_LAYOUT` in 2013.  If implemented, it should be reflected in `__min_cap` (which it currently isn't).

Comment: Thank you for the explanations, that is really helpful. One question though... why not use the MSBit as short / long flag? Wouldn't that free up 7 more bits for long string capacity...? Granted, that's mostly theoretical as the OS probably won't support heap allocations of that size. I was just wondering if I am missing a point somehow.

Comment: There's actually a twisty maze of options between `_LIBCPP_ABI_ALTERNATE_STRING_LAYOUT` and big/little endian where that short/long bit jumps around between MSB and LSB and I honestly don't recall the details.

Comment: @HowardHinnant whilst experimenting on Linux it appears that the SSO buffer is 16 bytes for both 32 and 64 bit implementations, supporting up to 15 characters.

Comment: Yes, that is true of the gcc implementation (libstdc++).  This Q/A is about the LLVM implementation (libc++):  https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/tree/main/libcxx

Answer (score 25):

The [libc++ implementation](http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/libcxx/trunk/include/string) is a bit complicated, I'll ignore its alternate design and suppose a little endian computer:

```
template <...>
class basic_string {
/* many many things */

    struct __long
    {
        size_type __cap_;
        size_type __size_;
        pointer   __data_;
    };

    enum {__short_mask = 0x01};
    enum {__long_mask  = 0x1ul};

    enum {__min_cap = (sizeof(__long) - 1)/sizeof(value_type) > 2 ?
                      (sizeof(__long) - 1)/sizeof(value_type) : 2};

    struct __short
    {
        union
        {
            unsigned char __size_;
            value_type __lx;
        };
        value_type __data_[__min_cap];
    };

    union __ulx{__long __lx; __short __lxx;};

    enum {__n_words = sizeof(__ulx) / sizeof(size_type)};

    struct __raw
    {
        size_type __words[__n_words];
    };

    struct __rep
    {
        union
        {
            __long  __l;
            __short __s;
            __raw   __r;
        };
    };

    __compressed_pair<__rep, allocator_type> __r_;
}; // basic_string
```

Note: `__compressed_pair` is essentially a pair optimized for the [Empty Base Optimization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ebo), aka `template <T1, T2> struct __compressed_pair: T1, T2 {};`; for all intents and purposes you can consider it a regular pair. Its importance just comes up because `std::allocator` is stateless and thus empty.

Okay, this is rather raw, so let's check the mechanics! Internally, many functions will call `__get_pointer()` which itself calls `__is_long` to determine whether the string is using the `__long` or `__short` representation:

```
bool __is_long() const _NOEXCEPT
    { return bool(__r_.first().__s.__size_ & __short_mask); }

// __r_.first() -> __rep const&
//     .__s     -> __short const&
//     .__size_ -> unsigned char
```

To be honest, I am not too sure this is Standard C++ (I know the initial subsequence provision in `union` but do not know how it meshes with an anonymous union and aliasing thrown together), but a Standard Library is allowed to take advantage of implementation defined behavior anyway.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer! The only piece I am missing is what `__min_cap` would evaluate to for different architectures, I am not sure what `sizeof()` will return and how it is influenced by aliasing.

Comment: @ValarDohaeris it's implementation defined. typically, you would expect `3 * the size of one pointer` in this case, which would be 12 octets on a 32 bit arch and 24 on a 64 bit arch.