Why crazy identifiers like `__x` are still used in standard libraries, since naming conflicts can be avoided easily in C++?
I was told that it's a way to avoid naming conflicts in C header files to use crazy names beginning with several _. In my opinion, in C++, naming conflicts can be avoided easily by namespace or something else, and there's no need to do so.
However, when I opened stl_vector.h by accident, I found such crazy names everywhere. I even found variables like __x inner a class (I do not think there could be conflicts for variables inner a class). I scanned several header files, and realized it's common. I wonder why.
My compiler is g++ (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0.

It's a convention for std invented ages ago. Everyone sticks to it, but noone truly knows why anymore.

Macros. There's no protection against them. Therefore such names are reserved. _D__x=__y and the standard library is ruined.

Like almost anything humans do... because it was needed/used in the past (and change has a momentum all of its own).  And there are still cases where things ar not put inside a namespace (legacy "C" api's). So the convention stuck. (And if it isn't broke don't fix it, changing to non __ variable might start breaking your and a lot of other code)

@273K That might be worth an answer (if there's no dupe for it).

Made typo, should be -D__x=__y

What are the rules about using an underscore in a C++ identifier?

"crazy names beginning with several _" -- Those names are "reserved", not "crazy". Calling them "crazy" calls into question how objective your question is. (If you stray too far into this territory, you risk your question becoming a "rant in disguise". Neutral terminology is better if you're actually interested in an answer. Maybe a single "crazy" to vent your frustration, but three is overdoing it a bit.)

@user12002570  I disagree with the dup.  It is about the rules concerning reserved identifiers.   It doesn't really address the reason for the rules, which (unnecessary ranting aside) is essentially what this question is about.   273K's comment touched on that (susceptibility of the standard library to behaving differently due to user macros is a real concern for as long as the preprocessor is part of standard C++).

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32807815/reasons-for-double-undescores-in-standard-library-implementations -- it's a duplicate of this rather. In short, you can do #define x 42 without affecting the std lib, because x is not reserved. Further, the std lib can #define __x 42 without affecting your code, because __x is reserved.

the whole point of you not being allow to use __x as identifier is that the library implementation can use it.

The crazy names in the standard headers are to avoid crazy macros that can crazy affect the standard headers.

If every programmer in the world promises to never write using namespace std; and promises to never define a macro that has the same name as any name used inside any implementation of the standard library there will be no need for this naming convention.
