# Fixed size string type container

Tags: c++, string, c++11, stl, containers

I need a fixed size string type for certain requirements. For now I've been doing a simple `char[20]` array of characters to meet this requirement. However, it is lacking certain stl container-friendly properties that I require now and then. For eg a simple `empty()`, `clear()` methods are required quite frequently and also the `length`/`size` property or `getSize()` method that might return this property or the ability to not manage '/0'. Not the actual size, but the size of string that fills the container.

Now I know I can reimplement all this and I might in the future when I get some time, but for now is there another way to achieve this?

Comment: You've just described a `std::string`.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik except it isn't fixed size. Eg `std::vector` vs `std::array`

Comment: You cannot have a "fixed size" when you want to have methods like 'clear()', which changes the size of the string. Make up your mind: either you want a fixed-size `std::array`, for example, in which case you have a fixed size array - no clear(), empty(), etc... - or you want a variable-length string, a.k.a. `std::string`.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik by clear in context of fixed size strings means fill with null.

Comment: Well, then, use `std::array<char, 10>`. Use `fill()` to clear it to nulls.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik except array dosen't track filled elements.

Comment: Well, then, pick one. The number of available containers in the C++ is quite small. Your option are: string, vector, or array. That's it. There's nothing else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that you want to hold the small string in-place, avoiding allocation on heap and indirection when accessing it. In that case, have a look at [`small_vector`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/container/non_standard_containers.html#container.non_standard_containers.small_vector) from Boost.

```
typedef boost::container::small_vector<char> small_string;
```

This would work as the string you want.

UPDATE: It seems that many implementations of standard C++ library use the small string optimization (SSO) for `std::string`. It means that as long as your string is small enough (for example 22 characters on 64 bit architecture) it will be stored in-place. I strongly suggest you to use standard `std::string` then.

Comment: where can I read more about SSO? my string might be 8-10 chars max but might've to support both 32 and 64 bit systems.

Comment: Found it - you can link it with your answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/21710033/4785903

Answer (score 1):

Since the question specifically asks for a fixed size string the current answer (`small_vector`) is wrong since it does not have fixed size.

The closest match would be [`std::array<char, N>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) as mentioned by @SamVarshavchik in the comments.