# No small string optimization with gcc?

Tags: c++, string, gcc, memory, optimization

Most `std::string` implementations (GCC included) use small string optimization. E.g. there's an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21710033/2640636) discussing this.

Today, I decided to check at what point a string in a code I compile gets moved to the heap. To my surprise, my test code seems to show that no small string optimization occurs at all!

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  std::string s;

  cout << "capacity: " << s.capacity() << endl;

  cout << (void*)s.c_str() << " | " << s << endl;
  for (int i=0; i<33; ++i) {
    s += 'a';
    cout << (void*)s.c_str() << " | " << s << endl;
  }

}
```

The output of `g++ test.cc && ./a.out` is

```
capacity: 0
0x7fe405f6afb8 | 
0x7b0c38 | a
0x7b0c68 | aa
0x7b0c38 | aaa
0x7b0c38 | aaaa
0x7b0c68 | aaaaa
0x7b0c68 | aaaaaa
0x7b0c68 | aaaaaaa
0x7b0c68 | aaaaaaaa
0x7b0c98 | aaaaaaaaa
0x7b0c98 | aaaaaaaaaa
0x7b0c98 | aaaaaaaaaaa
0x7b0c98 | aaaaaaaaaaaa
0x7b0c98 | aaaaaaaaaaaaa
0x7b0c98 | aaaaaaaaaaaaaa
0x7b0c98 | aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
0x7b0c98 | aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
0x7b0cd8 | aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
0x7b0cd8 | aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
0x7b0cd8 | aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
0x7b0cd8 | aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
0x7b0cd8 | aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
0x7b0cd8 | aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
0x7b0cd8 | aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
0x7b0cd8 | aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
0x7b0cd8 | aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
0x7b0cd8 | aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
0x7b0cd8 | aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
0x7b0cd8 | aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
0x7b0cd8 | aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
0x7b0cd8 | aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
0x7b0cd8 | aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
0x7b0cd8 | aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
0x7b0d28 | aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

I'm guessing that the larger first pointer, i.e. `0x7fe405f6afb8` is a stack pointer, and the other ones point to the heap. Running this many times produces identical results, in the sense that the first address is always large, and the other ones are smaller; the exact values usually differ. The smaller addresses always follow the standard power of 2 allocation scheme, e.g. `0x7b0c38` is listed once, then `0x7b0c68` is listed once, then `0x7b0c38` twice, then `0x7b0c68` 4 times, then `0x7b0c98` 8 times, etc.

After reading Howard's answer, using a 64bit machine, I was expecting to see the same address printed for the first 22 characters, and only then to see it change.

Am I missing something?

Also, interestingly, if I compile with `-O` (at any level), I get a constant small pointer value `0x6021f8` in the first case, instead of the large value, and this `0x6021f8` doesn't change regardless of how many times I run the program.

Output of `g++ -v`:

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/foo/bar/gcc-6.2.0/gcc/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/6.2.0/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-redhat-linux
Configured with: ../gcc-6.2.0/configure --prefix=/foo/bar/gcc-6.2.0/gcc --build=x86_64-redhat-linux --disable-multilib --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=gcc4-compatible --enable-bootstrap --enable-threads=posix --with-long-double-128 --enable-long-long --enable-lto --enable-__cxa_atexit --enable-gnu-unique-object --with-system-zlib --enable-gold
Thread model: posix
gcc version 6.2.0 (GCC)
```

Comment: `--with-default-libstdcxx-abi=gcc4-compatible`

Comment: @T.C. Really? `gcc4` didn't have small string optimization?

Comment: I thought I remembered that small string optimization had to be put (back) into the language

Comment: Thanks for the actual test code. Apparently, at least an empty string doesn't require heap allocation.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

One of your flags is:

```
--with-default-libstdcxx-abi=gcc4-compatible
```

and GCC4 does *not* support small string optimzation.

---

GCC5 started supporting it. [isocpp](https://isocpp.org/blog/2015/04/gcc-5.1-released) states:

> A new implementation of std::string is enabled by default, using the small string optimization instead of copy-on-write reference counting.

which supports my claim.

Moreover, [Exploring std::string](http://shaharmike.com/cpp/std-string/) mentions:

> As we see, older libstdc++ implements copy-on-write, and so it makes
>   sense for them to not utilize small objects optimization.

and then he changes context, when GCC5 comes in play.

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether the C++11 ABI is used by default if you call

```
gcc -v 2>&1 | sed -n 's/.*\(--with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new\).*/\1/p'
```

If you don't get a result, the old ABI is used. (Taken from the [Conan](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/howtos/manage_gcc_abi.html) doku)

Besides the reason given by gsamaras, the old ABI is also used in older Redhat versions, which are incompatible with the C++11 ABI: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1546704

Comment: This will only work if the `--with-default-libstdcxx-abi=` was explicitly passed to the GCC `configure` script.

Comment: Interesting. Would you consider checking for `_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI` to be safer? If yes, I'd change my answer.

Comment: The right term would be more reliable. This discussion is only tangentially relevant to the original question. I assume you are posting this for your own record.