# Why does taking a substring of length 23 take 5 times longer than substring of length 22 in clang?

Tags: c++, clang++

On clang version 5.0.1 the following code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    string str = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

    for (int i = 0; i < 5000000; i++) {
        str.substr(4);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

gives me the following timings

```
real    0m0.104s
user    0m0.096s
sys     0m0.002s
```

Now if I change it such that I have `str.substr(3)`, I end up with the following timings

```
real    0m0.478s
user    0m0.468s
sys     0m0.003s
```

As far as I can tell gcc does not suffer from this. Could anyone shed any light on what may the problem here?

EDIT:

More importantly, might anyone have a suggestion about how to avoid this huge performance hit?

EDIT2:

It appears likely this is some kind of short string optimisation trickery, particularly since [22 is magic number in that context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21694302/what-are-the-mechanics-of-short-string-optimization-in-libc).

Comment: Might be short-string-optimization, not sure though.

Comment: The traditional question: how do you compile your program, which compiler optimization parameters do you apply?

Comment: `clang++ -o test test.cpp`, while setting a optimisation level helps with the shorter string, it does not help on the longer string.

Comment: [Cannot reproduce on TIO](https://tio.run/##3ZC9UsMwEIR7PcVOKJJgYjJAKht30OYBGIqzrNgilmz0E/4mz27OTpihp@OaPe2svpnbknwzDJIC8hzzh@3jHAUolX0vLrSVbawUct354BSZ4pfHjrZ1IUT0rLBklO9JKvhQZUJoG2BI28W4kKvlFWRDDpe8H56el/gS4DlRRsE9ZlTKSu3qRr/sW2O7/tX5EA9v7x@fM0aO@V3nMCE159cZS47Nehp@JMkP98xOfSxZFnfLbLKPJ4pTITrL/8VR8MlCyJZsnSRYbW@w6kDnBoI2Cuk1ceCfF3T7x4KG4Rs).

Comment: I've edited the question. The example was originally `str.substr(str.find('e'))` and `str.substr(str.find('d'))` but I changed it for clarity and made a mistake.

Comment: This isn't how you microbenchmark. However, I'd guess the short string optimization made the optimizer made the correct inlining and eliminations to make it so fast. I doubt this is a big issue in practice

Comment: It's a big issue because the substr calls are taking up 4 minutes of a 6 minute computation, if I can fix this I can save at least 50% of my running time.