# This program is not printing whole string

Tags: c++, string

In this program,I store integer values from 0 to 4 in a string and I want to print this string.

**CODE:**

```
int main()
{
 string str=" ";
 for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
   str[i]=i+'0';
 cout<<str;
 return 0;
}
```

But when i run this program,it just shows first element(means '0') of string.

Can anybody tell me the reason,Why this program does not print whole string in output?

Comment: FYI -- Better to stay away from magic numbers and simply do `str[i] = i + '0';`

Comment: Undefined behaviour, due to writing 5 characters to a string that contains a single character.  Accessing `str[i]` with `i` out of bounds does not magically resize the string.

Comment: @Peter That's an _answer_. Not a comment. This is a Q&A. Not a chatroom. Many of your comments give solutions to the problem, an answer to the question. Please stop doing that. We have peer review in the answer section for a reason. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int main()
{
 string str=" ";        // str.size() == 1

 for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
   str[i]=i+'0';        // str.size() is still 1

 cout<<str;             // str.size() is still 1 
}
```

In `str[i]`, if ...

- `i>str.size()` you are accessing the array out of bounds and get undefined behaviour.
- `i==str.size()` (where the null terminator is) and you change that value, you also get undefined behaviour.

> But when i am printing this string with the help of for loop,this program prints whole string.e.g:
>
> ```
> for(int i=0; i<5; i++) {
>     cout<<str[i]<<" "; 
> }
> ```
>
> Why this loop print whole string, but not `cout<<str`?

You've made changes out of bounds and have undefined behaviour. It's possible that you can read the values back one-by-one (instead of getting a program crash) due to [short string optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21710033/7582247) - but the `size()` of `str` is still 1 since you haven't changed the size.

If your loop had gone further, outside the area used by short string optimization, like this:

```
for(int i=0; i<25; i++) {
    cout<<str[i]<<" "; 
}
```

it would be even more likely to result in a crash.

Answer (score 3):

The code doesn't work as expected because you exceeded the string greatest index which is `0` because the size of your string is `1` as the previous answer say.

This is a modification

```
int main()
{
    std::string str="     ";
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
        str[i]=i+'0';
    std::cout<<str;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually, when you are using for loop, it is accessing position in string changing it. Since when you have initialized string as `string str = " "` this means our string is of single whitespace. After which for loop access that string and look for the index `str[i]` and changes its value to `i+'0'`.

So, when we are writing code as

```
for(int i=0; i< 5; i++){
  str[i]=i+'0';
  cout<<str[i];
}
```

it seems, like for that block, str[i] value is i+'0', which is printed, but str doesn't update. Due to which when you do `cout<<str;` it again shows `0` as the answer.

To solve this issue we can use property of concatenation, refer the below code

```
 #include <iostream>
 using namespace std;

 int main()
 {
 string str;
 for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    str+=i+'0';
 cout<<str;
 return 0;
 }
```

This gives the required result as `01234`.

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 2):

You are exceeding array boundaries, because you initialized the string as containing only one space. If you give it more spaces, the code works:

```
string str = "     ";
```

Comment: But when i am printing this string with the help of for loop,this program prints whole string.e.g:for(int i=0;i<5;i++){  cout<<str[i]<<" ";  }.Why this loop print whole string,but not ( cout<<str ;  ).

Comment: @AmitNandal -- Did you make the changes suggested in the answer given to you?  If not, then your code has undefined behavior due to accessing elements out-of-bounds.

Comment: Sir,but when i print this string with the help of for loop,it show correct output(01234).

Comment: @AmitNandal It still is undefined behavior. That you observe output that matches your expectation is a possible manifestation of undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

when we are assigning

```
string str = " ";
```

here " " is of type `const char[2];`size is 2: 1 lenght of character and 1 length for '\0' (Null Terminated) character.
This gets copied into string str by calling `operator=` overloaded function.

When We are trying to access `str[]` with more than 0,1 index of subscript[] say 2 its doing memory violation and that is causing the exception *"string subscript out of range"*,

if you try to access [0] and [1] it will work fine or instead of accessing particular location using array subscript, concatenation (+=) will help.