# Calculate length of string object using pointers instead of char arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, string, string-length

I'm working on an exercise to calculate the length of a string using pointers.
Here's the code I've written below:

```
int main() {

    std::string text = "Hello World";
    std::string *string_ptr = &text; 
    int size = 0;

   //Error below: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]
    while (string_ptr != '\0') {
        size++;
        string_ptr++;
    }
    std::cout << size;
}
```

In a lot of examples that I've seen, the string is often a char array which I also understand is a string. However, I want to try calculate it as a string object but I'm getting the error below.

Is it possible to calculate it where the string is an object, or does it need to be a char array?

Comment: `std::string` has a `size` method.

Comment: using pointer will be `string_ptr->size()` :)

Comment: `std::string` has a method called `c_str` which returns a null terminated array. Use your logic on that instead

Comment: note that `string_ptr++` will increase the address in the `string_ptr` pointer by `sizeof(std::string)`

Comment: Useful additional reading is [What are the mechanics of short string optimization in libc++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21694302/what-are-the-mechanics-of-short-string-optimization-in-libc) which shows how the bytes of the std::string (which is of constant size) can be laid out in memory and details of how it stores a pointer to heap data when the string gets large.

Answer (score 6):

If you just want the size of the string, well, use `std::string::size()`:

```
auto size = text.size();
```

Alternatively, you can use `length()`, which does the same thing.

But I'm guessing you're trying to reimplement `strlen` for learning purposes. In that case, there are three problems with your code.

First, you're trying to count the number of *characters* in the string, and that means you need a pointer to `char`, not a pointer to `std::string`. That pointer should also point to constant characters, because you're not trying to modify those characters.

Second, to get a pointer to the string's characters, use its method `c_str()`. Getting the address of the string just gets you a pointer to the string itself, not its contents. Most importantly, the characters pointed to by `c_str()` are *null terminated*, so it is safe to use for your purposes here. Alternatively, use `data()`, which has been behaving identically to `c_str()` since C++11.

Finally, counting those characters involves checking if the value *pointed to* by the pointer is `'\0'`, so you'll need to dereference it in your loop.

Putting all of this together:

```
const char* string_ptr = text.c_str(); // get the characters
int size = 0;

while (*string_ptr != '\0') { // make sure you dereference the pointer
    size++;
    string_ptr++;
}
```

Of course, this assumes the string does not contain what are known as "embedded nulls", which is when there are `'\0'` characters before the end. `std::string` can contain such characters and will work correctly. In that case, your function will return a different value from what the string's `size()` method would, but there's no way around it.

For that reason, you should really just call `size()`.

Comment: Using c_str is an invalid approach. An object of the type std::string can contain embedded zero characters.

Comment: And using `strlen` with such a string would also give you invalid results, anyway. There's no way around it. For the purpose of this answer, I assumed the string did not contain embedded zero characters (and if it does, well, then you have to use `size()`, which kinda defeats the point of writing our own `strlen`, does it?)

Comment: You are wrong. In C strings are defined such a way that any zero character ends a string  by the definition of the notion string.

Comment: Yeah, sure, but this is an issue with the algorithm presented here, not `c_str()` itself. Do you have a better proposal, then, to get the length of a string without using `size()` or `length()`?

Comment: Such an algorithm with objects of the type std::string does not make a sense.

Answer (score 2):

First things first, the problem is irrelevant. [`std::string::size()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/size) is a O(1) (constant time) operation, as `std::string`'s typically store their size. Even if you need to know the length of a C-style string (aka `char*`), you can use [`strlen`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strlen). (I get that this is an exercise, but I still wanted to warn you.)

Anyway, here you go:

```cpp
size_t cstrSize(const char* cstr)
{
    size_t size(0);
    while (*cstr != '\0')
    {
        ++size;
        ++cstr;
    }
    return size;
}
```

You can get the underlying C-style string (which is a pointer to the first character) of a `std::string` by calling `std::string::c_str()`. What you did was getting a pointer to the `std::string` object *itself*, and dereferencing it would just give you that object back. And yes, you need to dereference it (using the `*` unary operator). That is why you got an error (which was on the `(string_ptr != '\0')` btw).

Answer (score 0):

You are totally confused here.

“text” is a std::string, that is an object with a size() method retuning the length of the string.

“string_ptr” is a pointer to a std::string, that is a pointer to an object. Since it is a pointer to an object, you don’t use text.size() to get the length, but string_ptr->size().

So first, no, you can’t compare a pointer with an integer constant, only with NULL or another pointer.

The first time you increase string_ptr it points to the memory after the variable text. At that point using *string_ptr for anything will crash.

Remember: std::string is an object.

Comment: "_you can’t compare a pointer with an integer constant_": Comparing a pointer with an integral literal with value `0` is exactly what _is_ possible (`NULL` is probably defined as just that). It fails here because it is a _character literal_ rather than an _integer literal_.