# How to reserve a vector of strings, if string size is variable?

Tags: c++, string, vector, reserved

I want to add many `string`s to a `vector`, and from what I've found, calling `reserve()` before this is more efficient. For a `vector` of `int`s, this makes sense because `int` is 4 bytes, so calling `reserve(10)` clearly reserves 40 bytes. I know the number of strings, which is about 60000. Should I call `vector.reserve(60000)`? How would the compiler know the size of my `string`s, as it doesn't know if these `string`s are of length 5 or 500?

Comment: By saying std::string is fixed at compile time, does that mean that if I have a string of 1000 bytes, that every string has 1000 bytes, even for short strings?

Comment: A `char *` can also represent a string of any size, and just like `std::string`, a `char *` is always the same size.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The compiler doesn't know the size of the strings, it knows the size of `std::string` object. Now, the size of `std::string` *object* does not depend on size of string. That is because - most of the time [1] - `std::string` will allocate on heap, so the object itself is only a pointer and length.

This also means, when you reserve the vector, you don't yet reserve memory for the strings. This is, however, not always a problem. `std::string`s come from somewhere: if the strings you receive are the return value of a function (i.e., you have them by value), then the memory is already allocated for the string (in the return value). Thus, e.g. `std::swap()` can help you speeding up populating the array with the results.

If however you populate it using passing references, then the callee will do the operations that result in alloc. In this case, you'd likely want to loop over the vector and reserve each string:

```
std::vector<std::string> v;
v.reserve(60000); // expected number of strings
for (auto& s : v) {
    s.reserve(500); // expected/max. size of strings
}
```

[1] It might occur that the specific implementation of `std::string` actually has a small, fixed-size buffer for sort strings and thus allocates only on heap when the string is longer than that.

Comment: The short string optimization is not a thing of the past, it is used by most modern implementations. It is copy-on-write that disappeared.

Comment: @MarcGlisse Thanks for the explanation, updated the answer. Yes, I remember the upgrades when cow went out of glibc...

Answer (score 0):

Roughly speaking, `std::string` implementation consists of a pointer to the character buffer which represents the string. This character buffer is dynamically allocated on the heap (not always the case, refer to [short string optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21694302/what-are-the-mechanics-of-short-string-optimization-in-libc)). So it really doesn't matter how much space you reserve for the vector, because none of it will be utilized for the character buffer, and for every string that you add in the vector, the character buffer will be dynamically allocated, leaving the extra reserved space unused.

The size of the `std::string` class is known at compile time, and is equal to `sizeof(std::string)`. In your case, you should just do something of the sort of `v.reserve(n * sizeof(std::string))` if you are expecting to insert `n` strings into the vector `v`.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to add many `string`s to a `vector`, and from what I've found, calling `reserve()` before this is more efficient.

If you know up front how many strings you want to store in the vector, then yes.

> For a `vector` of `int`s, this makes sense because `int` is 4 bytes, so calling `reserve(10)` clearly reserves 40 bytes.

Yes, as it is allocating memory for `sizeof(int) * 10` bytes.

> I know the number of strings, which is about 60000. Should I call `vector.reserve(60000)`?

Yes.

> How would the compiler know the size of my `string`s, as it doesn't know if these `string`s are of length 5 or 500?

The compiler doesn't need to know the *length* of the strings. Obviously, that is not known until runtime. However, that length doesn't change the *compile-time* size of the `std::string` class itself, which has a fixed layout and size. But one of its data members is a pointer to the actual character data, which is typically stored elsewhere in dynamic memory, thus is not counted toward the memory of the `std::string` object itself.

However, in the case of *Short-String Optimization*, the `std::string` class includes a small fixed buffer, which does count towards its fixed size at *compile-time*, and its data pointer will point at that buffer until the character data grows beyond the size of the buffer, then `std::string` will allocate dynamic memory to hold the larger character data. The SSO buffer still exists in the object, just unused at that point.

`reserve()` will allocate space only for the `std::string` objects themselves, not for any dynamic memory used for their character data. When a `std::string` object points at dynamic memory for its character data, that is irrelevant to the memory that `std::vector` allocates.

So yes, you would call `reserve(60000)` if you want to reserve space for 60000 `std::string` objects. That would allocate memory for `sizeof(std::string) * 60000` bytes in the `vector`.

So, in general, `reserve()` allocates `sizeof(vector::element_type) * capacity` number of bytes. Then the `vector` creates instances of the `element_type` inside that memory as needed.

Or, in other words, when you want to pre-allocate memory for `n` number of elements, you ask `reserve()` to allocate memory for `n` number of elements. Period. The details of what those elements do internally is irrelevant to the `vector`. That is for the elements to handle on their own.