Performance of passing std::string by value in constructor
Say I have this class:
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass(std::string str) : m_str(std::move(str)) {}
private:
    std::string m_str;
}

In modern C++, will this under any circumstance be less efficient than passing the string by const reference? I.e. if I have parameters that support move and the parameters are only copied to members and not otherwise used in the constructor can I always write code this way to get optimal performance?
The way I see it:

If the compiler does not do copy elision there is a copy, but that copy would have been needed anyway for a const reference (only in that case it would have been in the constructor rather than before calling the constructor).
If the compiler manages to utilize copy elision when passing the string to the constructor this solution should be a net benefit from using a const reference because there is now no copies what so ever.


I've heard that moving a string can be more expensive than copying it for short strings. But I wouldn't bother with this, since in general your approach is the best one.

inspect the compiled code

Advantages of pass-by-value and std::move over pass-by-reference and Passing a parameter to a function with std::move, is there a difference if that parameter is declared as pass-by-value or with a move operand &&?

this would force at least one copy when calling constructor. In this case a temporal std::string would be created using const char*, then it would be copied to argument.
    MyClass a("Hello");

And only then that copy would be moved into m_str. Using an rvalue reference would allow to move original temporal value (xvalue).
Similar situation happens with argument of function and NRO. Returning a local variable may avoid a copy - a local variable would represent returned value. Trying to return argument like this would guarantee a copy:
std::string foo(std::string arg) {
   return arg;
}

because in ABI the identity of returned value cannot match the identity of argument for technical reasons.
In case like this one may (ab)use perfect forwarding and "universal" reference:
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template<class... T>
concept Stringable = requires(T... a) { std::string(std::forward<T>(a)...); };

class MyClass {
public:    
    template<Stringable... Args> MyClass(Args&&... args)
       : m_str(std::forward<Args>(args)...) 
    { std::cout << m_str; }
private:
    std::string m_str;
};

int main()
{
   MyClass a {"Hello, world"}; 
}

Depending on argument types, this would cause tha a string would constructed only once, whole thing can be inlined, although that might be an excessive measure.

As it is described here, std::move acts literally like a typecasting to a constant one-time-reference. So, you should here avoid the copy semantics completely in favour of implicit referencing. So, the compiler should recognize the second case you mentioned:

If the compiler manages to utilize copy elision when passing the string to the constructor this solution should be a net benefit from using a const reference because there are now no copies whatsoever.

The problem here is an implicit platform-based optimization, like SSO, that could be applied to the internal representation of a string. For this, there is a very clear answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/28003328/9560245
Here we see, that the std::string class constructor should be called, either explicitly, or implicitly, and then we will have at least one place when the internal implementation of std::string will have (very likely!) a chance to produce a copy between a literal value converted to const char* to create an initial string. Thus your described case is just not a viable example of the situation where std::move will guarantee a performance benefit.

SSO is rather an optimization of free store's use than optimization of complexity cost, so normally I would diregard its "dangers". Depending on platform and implementations, free store requests outweight the move semantics turning into a copy.
