# Construction a vector from the concatenation of 2 vectors

Tags: c++, vector, constructor, initialization, addition

Is there a way to construct a `vector` as the concatenation of 2 `vector`s (Other than creating a helper function?)

For example:

```
const vector<int> first = {13};
const vector<int> second = {42};
const vector<int> concatenation = first + second;
```

I know that `vector` *doesn't* have an addition operator like `string`, but that's the behavior that I want. Such that `concatenation` would contain: 13 and 42.

I know that I can initialize `concatenation` like this, but it prevents me from making `concatenation` `const`:

```
vector<int> concatenation = first;
first.insert(concatenation.end(), second.cbegin(), second.cend());
```

Comment: literally first google result http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201718/concatenating-two-stdvectors

Comment: @RyanP Did I miss something in there that answered my question? Or perhaps I should assume that the answer to my question is no, since there wasn't anything in there that answered it?

Comment: If you can't use methods that modify the container and you don't want to use a helper method and there is no addition operator for vector then I'm afraid the answer to your question is no.

Comment: @JonathanMee I agree that it doesn't have the specific answer you are looking for and that maybe it was missed. But with 225 upvotes on the question, over 100k views, and that many answers personally I'd find it unlikely that if the solution you want existed it wouldn't have been mentioned, given that it would be the preferred answer to all of the answers that were given. In this case.

Comment: @RyanP I mean this is certainly possible using `basic_string<int>` but I'm not sure of the ramifications of such a misuse of `string`, but suffice to say it is possible.

Comment: @JonathanMee it is possible using `basic_string<int>`, but the question is about `std::vector`

Comment: @RyanP I'm curious now, if I'm just using this as a container, I wonder what the drawbacks of using `basic_string<int>` are?

Comment: @JonathanMee some of them http://stackoverflow.com/a/4557156/4525052

Comment: @RyanP it looks like other than a hint to the compiler all the differences were removed by C++11. I'm going to run a couple tests and see if this is viable.

Comment: @RyanP So after pretty thorough testing I'm certain this can be done, for `int`s and other smaller primitives only. You're right that it doesn't accomplish this using `vector<int>` which I note in [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35555016/2642059), so I'm not going to accept it, but I thought it might be useful information for someone other than me, so I've posted it here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, it's not possible if you require that

- no helper function is defined, and
- the resulting vector can be declared `const`.

Comment: I'm somewhat saddened to see that of all the answers I gave, it's this negative one which got me my gold C++ badge. :o[

Comment: @Reader I'm accepting this, but there is a hack that can circumnavigate this problem available here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35555016/2642059

Answer (score 2):

```
template<typename T>
std::vector<T> operator+(const std::vector<T>& v1, const std::vector<T>& v2){
    std::vector<T> vr(std::begin(v1), std::end(v1));
    vr.insert(std::end(vr), std::begin(v2), std::end(v2));
    return vr;
}
```

This does require a helper "function", but at least it allows you to use it as

```
const vector<int> concatenation = first + second;
```

Comment: Not very optimal just like the other answer.  This is going to cause at least one reallocation which can be expensive.

Comment: @NathanOliver: "This is going to cause at least one reallocation" - That depends on your implementation.  If first and second are less than the minimum vector size, then no it won't.

Comment: Optimal wasn't a requirement; the requirement was to allow concatenating two vectors into a const vector.  If avoiding re-allocations is a requirement, then the operator overload can be extended to initialize the movable return value with a reserve size of v1.size() + v2.size().

Comment: @MartinBonner I have to say I'm a little stunned that copying code from the question and blatantly disregarding the requirements of the question earns an upvote.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to write a help function.  I'd write it as:

```
std::vector<int> concatenate(const std::vector<int>& lhs, const std::vector<int>& rhs)
{
    auto result = lhs;
    std::copy( rhs.begin(), rhs.end(), std::back_inserter(result) );
    return result;
}
```

The call it as:

```
    const auto concatenation = concatenate(first, second);
```

If the vectors are likely to be very large (or contain elements that are expensive to copy), then you might need to do a `reserve` first to save reallocations:

```
std::vector<int> concatenate(const std::vector<int>& lhs, const std::vector<int>& rhs)
{
    std::vector<int> result;
    result.reserve( lhs.size() + rhs.size() );
    std::copy( lhs.begin(), lhs.end(), std::back_inserter(result) );
    std::copy( rhs.begin(), rhs.end(), std::back_inserter(result) );
    return result;
}
```

(Personally, I would only bother if there was evidence it was a bottleneck).

Comment: You can do this with 0 reallocations of `result`.

Comment: OP is asking how to do it without a helper function (I also failed to see that initially.)

Comment: @LogicStuff: Yes, you can - but I suggest it's probably not worth the extra complexity unless you know that function is going to be heavily used.  Reallocating vectors is really not that expensive.

Comment: @MartinBonner What.? If the vector has a 1,000,000 elements in it then you have 1,000,000 copies/moves to do when the reallocation happens.

Comment: @juanchopanza: Yes.  And my answer was intended to be read as "No. You cannot *initialize* a vector as a concatenation of two vectors without writing a helper function; here's how you write the helper function."

Comment: @NathanOliver: If the result vector has 1,000,000 elements, then the absolute *minimum* number of copy/moves is 1,000,000.  If you don't add a reserve at the front, the worst case is that you will end up doing something like 2,000,0000 copy/moves - which is only twice as bad.

Comment: @MartinBonner Which goes against your statement: *Reallocating vectors is really not that expensive.*

Comment: 2,000,000 copies/moves is expensive in my book.  If you reserve the space ahead of time then it save a lot.

Comment: @LogicStuff: Bah humbug!  Thanks.  Fixed.

Comment: @NathanOliver:  It only goes against my statement, if I accept your premise that 2,000,000 copy/moves (actually 1,000,000 extra) is a lot.  I don't (unless there is evidence to the contrary).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103866/discussion-between-nathanoliver-and-martin-bonner).

Answer (score 0):

```
class Vector : public vector<int>
{
public:
    Vector operator+(const Vector& vec);
};

Vector Vector::operator+(const Vector& vec)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++)
    {
        this->push_back(vec[i]);
    }

    return *this;
}
```

Comment: This not only *does* require writing an additional function, but it also requires me to create and use a non-standard class, and it exhibits a far more virulent version of the reallocation problem than does @MartinBonner 's answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35485866/vector-construction-from-the-concatenation-of-2-vectors?noredirect=1#comment58665572_35486013

Answer (score 0):

Let me preface this by saying this is a hack, and will *not* give an answer to how to do this using a `vector`. Instead we'll depend on `sizeof(int) == sizeof(char32_t)` and use a `u32string` to contain our data.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35558008/2642059) makes it exceedingly clear that *only* primitives can be used in a `basic_string`, and that any primitive larger than 32-bits would require writing a custom `char_traits`, but for an `int` we can just use `u32string`.

The qualification for this can be validated by doing:

```
static_assert(sizeof(int) == sizeof(char32_t));
```

Once size equality has been established, and with the knowledge that things like non-`const` `data`, and `emplace` or `emplace_back` cannot be used, `u32string` can be used like a `vector<int>`, with the notable inclusion of an addition opperator:

```
const vector<int> first = {13};
const vector<int> second = {42};
const u32string concatenation = u32string(first.cbegin(), first.cend()) + u32string(second.cbegin(), second.cend());
```

[[Live Example](http://ideone.com/7Iww3I)]

Answer (score 0):

I came across this question looking for the same thing, and hoping there was an easier way than the one I came up with... seems like there isn't.

So, some iterator trickery should do it if you don't mind a helper template class:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
class concat
{
public:
    using value_type = typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator::value_type;
    using difference_type = typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator::difference_type;
    using reference = typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator::reference;
    using pointer = typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator::pointer;
    using iterator_category = std::forward_iterator_tag;
    concat(
        const std::vector<T>& first,
        const std::vector<T>& last,
        const typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator& iterator) : 
            mFirst{first},
            mLast{last},
            mIterator{iterator}{}
    bool operator!= ( const concat& i ) const
    {
        return mIterator != i.mIterator;
    }
    concat& operator++()
    {
        ++mIterator;
        if(mIterator==mFirst.end())
        {
            mIterator = mLast.begin();
        }
        return *this;
    }
    reference operator*() const
    {
        return *mIterator;
    }
private:
    const std::vector<T>& mFirst;
    const std::vector<T>& mLast;
    typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator mIterator;
};

int main()
{
    const std::vector<int> first{0,1,2,3,4};
    const std::vector<int> last{5,6,7,8,9};
    const std::vector<int> concatenated(
        concat<int>(first,last,first.begin()),
        concat<int>(first,last,last.end()));
    for(auto i: concatenated)
    {
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You may have to implement operator++(int) or operator== depending on how your STL implements the InputIterator constructor, this is the minimal iterator code example I could come up with for MingW GCC.

Have Fun! :)