# Is std::basic_string a ReversibleContainer?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, stdstring

I was documenting a piece of code, writing that we need the chosen container to be a `ReversibleContainer`.
Reading in details the description for `std::vector` and `std::basic_string`:

- For [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) and under its member types section (iterator), we read respectively:

> `std::vector` (for T other than `bool`) meets the requirements of `Container`, `AllocatorAwareContainer`(since C++11), `SequenceContainer`, `ContiguousContainer`(since C++17) and `ReversibleContainer`.

> `LegacyRandomAccessIterator` and `LegacyContiguousIterator` to `value_type`

- For [`std::basic_string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) and under its member types section, we read:

> `std::basic_string` satisfies the requirements of `AllocatorAwareContainer` (except that customized construct/destroy are not used for construction/destruction of elements), `SequenceContainer` and `ContiguousContainer`(since C++17).

> `LegacyRandomAccessIterator` and `LegacyContiguousIterator` to `value_type`

It seems to me `std::basic_string` meets all the requirements to be a [ReversibleContainer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/ReversibleContainer)the same way `std::vector` does, yet is not described as such.
Not my question but I also do not understand why it is not described as a `Container` the same way `std::vector` is.

Any idea why it was like this?

Comment: `std::basic_string` is not a ReversibleContainer, because a string can contain multi-byte characters and such string can't be properly iterated in reverse with reverse iterators. BTW it was a ReversibleContainer until C++11.

Comment: I think the standard intentionally doesn't mention that `basic_string` is a reversible container even though it looks like it, because the standard doesn't specify the complexity of those members that `basic_string` corresponds to, which is required by the reversible container requirements.

Comment: The standard doesn't claim that `basic_string` is a SequenceContainer either. Actually, it only says `vector`, `forward_list`, `list`, and `deque` are sequence containers   ([\[sequence.reqmts\]](http://eel.is/c++draft/sequence.reqmts#1.sentence-2)).

Comment: @273K I have failed to understand what you mean... `std::basic_string<T>::iterator` meets LegacyRandomAccessIterator, which makes it possible to iterate in reverse. Besides, why was it possible to write that `std::vector<bool>` does not meet the same requirements as vector on other types but not `basic_string`?

Comment: @273K `std::basic_string` is not aware of encodings. It simply stores a sequence of code units, regardless whether multiple of them are needed to form a character or code point. Iterators act on this code unit level.

Comment: @Atmo That `std::vector<bool>` was made a special case with different semantics is widely regarded as a mistake.

Comment: @user17732522 The point was not about whether it is a mistake or not. It was: since such a sentence exists for `vector` but not for `string`, the only conclusion I can draw is that the requirements are met for all types passed as template parameter, including for `std::string = std::basic_string<char>` -> thus I failed to understand @273K's comment (but read yours).

Comment: What can't you understand? Just the container meets *LegacyRandomAccessIterator*, which makes it possible to iterate in reverse is not enough, is necessary but not sufficient to declare the container a *ReversibleContainer*.

Comment: @user17732522 `std::basic_string` is not aware of encodings, but the standard authors are aware of encodings, the standard declares if a container is *ReversibleContainer* or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only thing I see in the *[reversible container](https://eel.is/c++draft/container.rev.reqmts#def:container,reversible)* requirements that isn't reflected in the specification of `std::basic_string` is that the `rbegin`/`rend`/`crbegin`/`crend` member functions lack the constant-time complexity requirement ([[string.iterators]](https://eel.is/c++draft/string.iterators)). `std::basic_string`'s member functions have no such complexity guarantee.

I am not sure whether this is intentional, since a `std::basic_string` has a constant time-complexity requirement on its `size` member function ([[string.capacity]](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.string#string.capacity)). So a `std::basic_string` implementation should also always be able to obtain `rbegin` in constant time. @JanSchultke has opened a [LWG issue](http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-active.html#4029) to propose clarifying that `std::basic_string`'s iterator functions have constant time complexity.

Otherwise it seems to me that they are reversible containers and the proposed resolution for the LWG issue mentioned above would clarify that `std::basic_string` ought to be a *reversible container*.

Comment: However, cppreference mentions all these methods (`rbegin`/`rend`/`crbegin`/`crend`) do have constant complexity (see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/rbegin) and [there](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/rend)). Iterators would not be [LegacyRandomAccessIterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomAccessIterator) if elements could not be accessed in constant time. Basically, everything I can read does not confirm that point.

Comment: @Atmo I see no justification for cppreference writing that the member functions are constant time complexity. It is not part of the LegacyRandomAccessIterator requirements which do not say anything about these methods as they aren't even part of the iterator. The iterator can allow constant-time access while obtaining the end of the sequence is not constant time (imagine e.g. a null-terminated string). But as I wrote, I think that is a defect in the standard, because other member functions are specified in such a way that obtaining the end should always be possible in constant time.

Comment: You are losing me... It is you writing "*The only thing I see in the reversible container requirements that isn't reflected in the specification of std::basic_string is that the `rbegin`/`rend`/`crbegin`/`crend` member functions lack the constant-time complexity requirement*". But in fact, as written in the 3 links I shared, it appears all the operations on iterators are O(1) for basic_string, or rather **specified** aka **guaranteed** to be O(1): `begin`, `end`, `rbegin`, `rend`, in/decrementing an iterator by any value, you name it.

Comment: And indeed, `size()` is O(1) too since C++11, although strangely enough, 273K has posted in comment to my question that `basic_string` was a ReversibleContainer until C++11. I have not found the source for that statement... I will wait a while to see if anyone disagrees with the final sentence of your answer and if nothing, will accept it.

Comment: @Atmo You are referencing cppreference.com which is just a community-mantained language reference in the style of Wikipedia. I am saying that the actual ISO C++ standard doesn't seem to agree. See for example in the current draft, see [\[string.iterators\]](https://eel.is/c++draft/string.iterators). The specifications lack a "Complexity:" entry (compare with e.g. [\[string.capacity\]](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.string#string.capacity)

Comment: @Atmo I don't see any basis for 273K's comment. See also my answer to them.

Comment: I see your point now ([methods returning iterators for other containers](https://eel.is/c++draft/container.requirements) also have the "Complexity" entry in the draft). FYI, the comment on an [old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4557009/vector-vs-string/4557156#4557156) (2010) about the difference between `string` and `vector` says: "*string originally wasn't an STL container. Against the advice of Pete Becker, the whole rest of the committee decided to make it one.*". This could be related but it is so old I gave up looking up for more info.

Comment: The fact that `basic_string` fails to meet the requirements is almost certainly a mistake. I have submitted a LWG issue which suggests to add the `Complexity: Constant.` paragraphs where needed.

Comment: @Atmo The current standard wording, "_Returns_: An iterator which is semantically equivalent to `reverse_iterator(end())`." (or "reverse_iterator(begin())" for `rend`/`crend`), is quite verbose and seemingly allows non-constant compexity. This is certainly a defect to me, and it seems that "_Effects_: equivalent to ..." should be used.

Comment: @user17732522 I've opened a LWG issue about this: http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-active.html#4029 Can you reference this in your answer?