# Why does the size of a derived class include private members from the base class?

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have the following code:

```
class A {
  private:
    int i;
 };

class B : public A {
 private:
  int j;
 };
```

When I check `sizeof(B)`, it appears to be `sizeof(base) + sizeof(derived)`. However, my understanding of inheritance is that the `private` members of a base class are not inherited. Why then are they included in the result of `sizeof(B)`?

Comment: More general question: [Difference between private, public and protected inheritance in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/860339/difference-between-private-public-and-protected-inheritance-in-c)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You either misunderstand `sizeof` or your misunderstand the layout (in memory) of C++ objects.

For performance reason (to avoid the cost of indirection), compilers will often implement Derivation using Composition:

```
// A
+---+
| i |
+---+

// B
+---+---+
| A | j |
+---+---+
```

Note that if `private`, `B` cannot peek in `A` even though it contains it.

The `sizeof` operator will then return the size of `B`, including the necessary padding (for alignment correction) if any.

If you want to learn more, I heartily recommend [Inside the C++ Object Model](http://www.amazon.fr/Inside-Object-Model-Stanley-Lippman/dp/0201834545) by *Stanley A. Lippman*. While compiler dependent, many compilers do in fact use the same basic principles.

Comment: How exactly would this be implemented *without* doing it this way? (Vis a vis cost of indirection?)

Comment: @Billy: you could decide that the base classes are embedded via a pointer (created by `new` and removed by `delete`). Then the base class would always occupy 4 or 8 bytes (depending on the system). It would be somewhat better ABI wise, but much more costly.

Comment: M.: Actually, you cannot do that. If it is created as an automatic variable, then it has to exist in automatic storage. Using something like `new` would be putting it in dynamic storage. (Moreover, if all you had was a base class pointer you'd have no way to get back to the derived parts of the object -- the bases don't know about their derivers)

Comment: @Billy: Automatic variable does not mean *stack*, it means the memory is managed for you. Good point wrt getting from base to derived, but your forget that it's already solved for virtual inheritance (although it IS costlier).

Comment: Most inheritance is not virtual. I don't see how that solves anything.

Comment: @Billy: I didn't say it solved anything, I merely point out that the Standard does not mandate the object representation, this is a compiler writer decision, and the mechanism of virtual inheritance could be used for regular inheritance too, in which case `sizeof` would not be affected by the size of the base class. There is no C++ implementation that I know of who uses such a wasteful scheme though.

Comment: I think that falls under the category of things that aren't technically mandated, but are implied, by the standard, such as [`std::basic_string::operator`(brackets) returning a reference to a contained character type in a contiguous buffer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2256160/how-bad-is-code-using-stdbasic-stringt-as-a-contiguous-buffer). (Can't use [] above because the linkification eats it...)

Comment: @Billy: no idea, I am still not versed enough in Standardese to understand all the rules, so *deducing* them is quite out of reach :D

Answer (score 8):

all member variables are inherited. the `private protected public` modifiers  only alter who has *access* to those variables

Answer (score 6):

You misunderstand what `private` does. In your code snippet it simply prevents non-members and non-friends of `A` from accessing `i`. It's just an *access-control* modifier. Instances of `B` will have data members of `A`, even though `B` won't have (direct) access to it.

An analogy that shows that this does in fact make sense:

```
class Human
{
protected:
    void UseCognitivePowers() { brain.Process(); }
private:
    Brain brain;
    // ...
};

class StackOverflowUserInSilico : public Human
{
private:
    void AnswerStackOverflowQuestion(int questionId)
    {
        // ...
        // magic occurs here
        // ...
        UseCognitivePowers();
    }
};
```

Even though `brain` is private in the `Human` class, `StackOverflowUserInSilico` will have a `Brain` since `StackOverflowUserInSilico` derives from `Human`. This is needed, otherwise the `UseCognitivePowers()` function won't work even though `StackOverflowUserInSilico` inherits the method from `Human`.

Of course whether subclasses of `Human` will actually take advantage of the `UseCognitivePowers()` method afforded to them by the `Human` class is a totally different matter.

Comment: @David: That's because the argument is wrong. The correct argument is: _X is a human, humans have brains, therefore X has a brain_ which is perfectly reasonable.

Answer (score 3):

It is inherited - the derived class object will contain it, but it can't be accessed by member functions of the derived class.

Comment: hey..thanks a lot..so the derived class inherits every thing,but the derived class public member functions cannot access the private members of base class ri8!

Answer (score 3):

This has already been answered in a few other answers: access specifiers restrict *access*, but the member attributes of the class are still inherited.

I just wanted to provide a rationale, as I usually learn better when I see the reasons for that. Basically, when you inherit from an type, the derived type *contains* a subobject of the base type, as small or large as the base might be. The reason for *needing* all of the member variables is that the derived object *is* a base object, and base level member functions can be called on it. Even if the derived type cannot access the private member attribute, the base methods that can be called on that object might still need to access it, so the members must be there:

```
class base {
   int x;
public:
   base() : x(0) {}
// ...
   void printout() {
      std::cout << x << std::endl;
   }
};
class derived : public base {
// ... assume that derived does not hide `printout`
};
int main() {
   derived d;
   d.printout();  // this requires access to d.base::x
}
```

This is only a simple example, and there are a few things that you can say here to argue that in some cases `x` can be made *unneeded* (we are overriding/hiding `printout` in the derived object...) but the language still allows you to access a hidden/overridden member method by qualifying, so `d.base::printout()` would still access `printout` at the base level, and that in turns requires `x`.

Answer (score 0):

**Access specifiers (public/private/protected) don't affect inherited "object size" in anyway.**

Comment: They do. They control which members of the class will be visible in the drived class.

Comment: @iammilind: they do affect the size too. Because of an arcane rule that stipulates that they affect the layout of the class, changing a specifier might change the final class size...

Comment: Matthieu's right - 11.1-2 and 9.2-12 - vaguely recall discussions of this allow an each check re the member's offset to also indicate the protection level (i.e. if (some_class_member.offset >= first_private_offset) /* it's private */). It might have also been an attempt to facilitate use of some real or postulated run-time security mechanism (e.g. with hardware allowing fine-grained memory access control, lock/unlock privates as private member functions called/return). Anyway, alignment rules mean order can affect efficiency of padding.

Answer (score 0):

i dont know what language this is, but when you inherit the original object still exists. that is why you can still call base.method()