# Is size of the object affected by type of access-specifier and type of inheritance?

Tags: c++, inheritance, access-specifier

While answering one of the question, there was a discussion thread [below my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6568656/why-the-size-of-derived-class-increased-even-though-the-base-class-member-is-pri/6568693#6568693). Which suggests that depending on the access specifier (or may be the type of inheritance) `private/protected/public` the `sizeof` the `class` object may vary!

I still don't understand from their brief discussion, how is that possible ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Note new language for C++11 below**

**In C++03**, there is language that makes this possible, 9.2 [class.mem]/12 (emphasis mine):

> Nonstatic data members of a (non-union) class declared **without an intervening access-specifier** are allocated so that later members have higher addresses within a class object. **The order of allocation of nonstatic data members separated by an access-specifier is unspecified** (11.1). Implementation alignment requirements might cause two adjacent members not to be allocated immediately after each other; so might requirements for space for managing virtual functions (10.3) and virtual base classes (10.1).

So given this definition:

```
class Foo
{
    char a; //8 bits
    // a must come before b, so 3 bytes of padding have to go here to satisfy alignment
    int b; //32 bits
    char c; //8 bits
    // 24 bits of padding required to make Foo a multiple of sizeof(int)
};
```

on a system with 32 bit (`int`) alignment, the compiler is not allowed to reorder `c` to come before `b`, forcing the insertion of additional padding padding in between `a` and `b`, and after `c` to the end of the object (making `sizeof(Foo) == 12`). However, for this:

```
class Foo
{
    char a;
public:
    int b;
public:
    char c;
};
```

`a` and (`b` and `c`) are separated by an access specifier, so the compiler is free to perform such reordering, making

```
memory-layout Foo
{
    char a; // 8 bits
    char c; // 8 bits
    // 16 bits of padding
    int b; // 32 bits
};
```

`sizeof(Foo) == 8`.

**In C++11**, the language changes slightly. N3485 9.2 [class.mem]/13 says (emphasis mine):

> Nonstatic data members of a (non-union) class **with the same access control** (Clause 11) are allocated so that later members have higher addresses within a class object. **The order of allocation of non-static data members with different access control is unspecified** (Clause 11). Implementation alignment requirements might cause two adjacent members not to be allocated immediately after each other; so might requirements for space for managing virtual functions (10.3) and virtual base classes (10.1).

This means that in C++11, in the above example (separated by 3 publics), the compiler is still not allowed to perform the reordering. It would have to be something like

```
class Foo
{
    char a;
public:
    int b;
protected:
    char c;
};
```

, which places `a`, `b`, and `c` with different access control.

Note that under the C++11 rules, given a definition like:

```
class Foo
{
    char a;
public:
    int b;
protected:
    char c;
public:
    int d;
};
```

the compiler must put `d` after `b`, even though they are separated by access specifiers.

---

(That said, I'm not aware of any implementation that actually takes advantage of the latitude offered by either standard)

Comment: The above being true & it does nicely answer the Q, but How does the Q really affect a user? One **MUST** always use the `sizeof` operator to get size of any type and no implementation should make assumptions about the size of class/struct because compilers are free to pad them anyways.

Comment: @Als: It could make a difference if you were doing something like `memcpy`ing a structure to a buffer with different compilers on either end. This content in the standard means that it has to work so long as alignment/endian requirements end up being the same, it will "just work" that way. (As for the usefulness to the user, yes, it's kind of useless, again, because nobody takes advantage of this latitude. But I answered the question asked... not trying to pass judgment on the OP)

Comment: Actually `sizeof(Foo)` will be `8` too, because it is always computed for arrays, so that you can use `malloc` to allocate the space of an array. Introducing a second `char c` after `b` would help you illustrate your point.

Comment: I think your proposed layour is forbidden because b must come before c.

Comment: @Bruno: I also updated the answer to reflect changes in wording in C++11.