# Why do I get the same value with and without dereferencing a pointer

Tags: c++, pointers

The following code :

```
int number = 65;
char *ptr = reinterpret_cast< char* >(&number);
cout << *ptr << endl;
```

`*ptr` prints `A` and `ptr` prints `A`. Why do they both print the same result ?

Comment: Your way of type-converting an int to a char is relying on implementation defined behaviour.  In this case, it will only work for little endian systems.

Comment: please add the appropriate language tag

Answer (score 4):

The streams are overloading `<<` such that the dereferencing is done implicitly for `char` anyway.

More specifically: Since `char *` is the `string` of C, `ostream` tries to read it as such, i.e. it dereferences the pointer and reads `char`s until it finds a zero byte. (This works only for the correct [Endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).)

Consider this code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(void) {
        char c = 'A';
        int  i = 66;
        std::cout <<  c << '\n';
        std::cout << &c << '\n';
        std::cout <<  i << '\n';
        std::cout << &i << '\n';
        return 0;
}
```

On my machine (**Not on all!**) it prints

```
A
AB
66
0x7fff0d1db1bc
```

because `c` is printed correctly, but `&c` is interpreted as string. But `c`is not null-terminated so `ostream` continues reading, finding the first byte of `i` and then finally a null byte, since the value of `i` is so small we only use one of its four bytes.

However, `i` and `&i` are printed as expected. This behaviour is only implemented for `char` as it makes no sense for other types.

Answer (score 1):

Both print the same result because:

1. `ostream::operator<<` has, among others, an overload for `char*` and `char` (see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2) and [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt)).
2. The `char*` overload interprets the argument as a pointer to a [null-terminated byte string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte), opposed to as a pointer to a single `char`.
3. Apparently your machine is [little endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) and has `sizeof(char) < sizeof(int)` (opposed to ==). That means that the memory occupied by `number`, when interpreted as an array of `char`s, is a `char` of value 65 followed by one or more null `char`s. Thus when `number` is interpreted as a null-terminated byte string, it contains a single character of value 65.

Thus when you stream `*ptr`, which is of type `char`, the `char` overload prints the character pointed which has value 65. When you stream `ptr`, which is of type `char*`, the `char*` overload prints the null-terminated byte string pointed to, which contains a single character of value 65, so again the single character is printed.

Further Notes regarding point 3:

Note that given `sizeof(char) < sizeof(int)` you're guaranteed to get a null-terminated byte string with exactly one character in it because `CHAR_BIT` is [at least 8](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/intrinsic-types#bits-per-byte). I.e. it's not possible that the value 65 does not fit into a single `char`.

Maybe your machine has `sizeof(char) == sizeof(int)` (in which case the endianess doesn't matter), and it's just coincidence that the memory after `number` is a null character, building again a thing which looks like a null-terminated byte string. I say looks like because it only really is one if you're allowed to read the terminating null character. Since on most systems `CHAR_BIT` is 8 (which is [required by POSIX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6631491/why-did-posix-mandate-char-bit-8)), and since the standard requires `int` to be [at least 32 bits](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types), it's highly unlikely that your machine has `sizeof(char) == sizeof(int)`.