# std::string to char*

Tags: c++, string, char

I want to convert a **std::string** into a **char*** or **char[]** data type.

```
std::string str = "string";
char* chr = str;
```

Results in: **“error: cannot convert ‘std::string’ to ‘char’ ...”**.

What methods are there available to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert a std::string to const char\* or char\*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347949/how-to-convert-a-stdstring-to-const-char-or-char)

Answer (score 837, accepted):

It won't automatically convert (thank god). You'll have to use the method `c_str()` to get the C string version.

```
std::string str = "string";
const char *cstr = str.c_str();
```

`.c_str()` returns a `const char *`. If you want a non-const `char *`, use `.data()`:

```
std::string str = "string";
char *cstr = str.data();
```

---

Some other options:

- Copying the characters into a vector:

  ```
  std::vector<char> cstr(str.c_str(), str.c_str() + str.size() + 1);
  ```

  Then `cstr.data()` will give you the pointer.

  This version copies the terminating `\0`. If you don't want it, remove `+ 1` or do `std::vector<char> cstr(str.begin(), str.end());`.
- Copying into a manually allocated array: (should normally be avoided, as manual memory management is easy to get wrong)

  ```
  std::string str = "string";
  char *cstr = new char[str.size() + 1];
  std::strcpy(cstr, str.c_str());
  // do stuff
  delete [] cstr;
  ```

Comment: @Kerrek SB: It was an example, would use a smart pointer in real code, or more likely avoid this `c_str` madness completely.

Comment: The answer is bulky, inelegant, non-local, uses raw arrays, and requires attention to exception safety. `vector` was invented precisely as a wrapper for dynamic arrays, so not using it seems like a missed opportunity at best, and in violation of the spirit of C++ at worst.

Comment: First of all, yes the answer is bulky. First I explain the OP's error (thinking that `std::string` would automatically convert) and then I explain what he should use, with a short code sample. Thinking forward I also explain some side effects of the use of this function, of which one is that you may not edit the string returned by `c_str()`. You mistakenly see my short examples as real problem-solving code, which it's not.

Comment: I downvoted the answer.  This answer is indeed not useful and the fact that it was accepted is most unfortunate.  This answer completely disregards good C++ programming practices and exception safety and there are far superior solutions, some of which are given in other answers to this question (e.g. the answer given by ildjarn which uses `std::vector<char>`).

Comment: @nightcracker I was not expecting it to convert automatically, I just did not know how to make the conversion and gave that code as example to demonstrate what I was trying to achieve. I understand that some types have nothing to do with others even if they look similar at first glance.

Comment: @james-mcnellis, I picked this answer as the correct one because it answered **EXACTLY** what I was asking for... No more, no less. I did not ask for what you think that I should do, I did not ask for a different solution for what you think that I am doing, I did not ask for good practices. You have no idea what I am working in, where my code is going to be implemented and under what conditions.  Some should learn to read, understand questions and to answer what is actually being asked. No need to show off here.

Comment: @Mario: Fair enough. It's not always obvious what the exact thing is that you're after. In this case, you seem to prefer adding manual memory management (along with its adherent complexity) to your solution, and that's fine; it was just not obvious from the start that that was part of your goals.

Comment: @kerrek, dont worry, a 10 bytes `char` data to call a single function once in my program won’t ruin my life. I wish that the author of that function expected something better than plain old char arrays but well, I sure can overcome this sad hit in my life.

Comment: @Mario: What's the function if I may ask? I've just smacked my head over a similar interface in the `mcrypt` functions which require mutable char arrays for blatantly constant strings...

Comment: @kerrek its a function I got somewhere, for me to be able to comunicate with bash scripts... I do not remember where I got it from, but it only accepted a char* as argument and changing it required too much code to be modified.

Comment: shouln't it be delete[] cstr; for the last line... not the author has put a space between delete and [] which is wrong. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/operator%20delete[]/

Comment: @Deb Are you seriously referencing [cplusplus.com](http://cplusplus.com/)? The actual C++11 standard actually defines `delete [ ]`, with the exception that _"Whenever the delete keyword is immediately followed by empty square brackets, it shall be interpreted as the second alternative."_ (the second alternative is `delete [ ]` in the original text).

Comment: I think many are missing the point of the complaints about this answer. I agree that this answers the question most simply, but a lot of coders are going to come to this question and not realize that there exists better alternatives from using a char *. It's worth it to include the alternatives as well.

Comment: To get an actual char* in the "modern" implementation, you might want to do: std::vector<char> cvec(str.c_str(), str.c_str() + str.size() + 1); char *cstr = cvec.data();

Comment: Why isn't the modern C++ answer `std::vector<char> cstr(begin(str), end(str));` ?

Comment: @Zitrax `cstr` is not null-terminated in your example.

Comment: For everyone complaining about the memory allocation and use of char*: sometimes you have APIs which you can't change that take `(char* str, int start, int end)` and modify char* returning a new end.  This is a solution for wrapping the call and allowing a new api of `std::string`.

Comment: The "modern alternative" of this answer should be much more prominent than the out-dated `new[]` solution. But still, the real modern alternative is to use `.data()` which returns a non-const `char*`.

Comment: This answer is long and causes a danger in memory leak if memory is not deleted properly with delete[].  How does it even deserve so many upvotes?  Look at the answer by bobobobo, aka. the actual clean way of removing the const by grabbing the memory address to the 0th position of the string.

Comment: I took liberty to edit this into the proper shape. I hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 247):

[More details here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4152881/111307), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10916896/111307) but you can use

```
string str = "some string" ;
char *cstr = &str[0];
```

As of C++11, you can also use the [`str.data()`](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/data/) member function, which returns `char *`

```
string str = "some string" ;
char *cstr = str.data();
```

Comment: FWIW, in my book, this is the only correct answer to the question that was actually asked. An std::string is inherently mutable: people who are making it sound like modifying the contents of the string is somehow the devil's work seem to be missing this fact.

Comment: yes, this is the correct answer.   it's silly that, given the frequency of use, there isn't a standart method to do this, like msoft's lockbuffer.

Comment: I changed 0 to 0u.   Because some compilers/libraries will (believe it or not) complain about some ambiguity when warnings are turned all the way on for the &str[0] construct

Comment: I doubt when the str is deleted, the char *cstr is made null. So I guess here only a pointer of the string is assigned to the char pointer. So the conversion of string to char* is not literally complete. String is only pointed to char* but its value is not converted. Am I correct???

Comment: Note that this is C++11 only. Previous versions might not have continuous storage or are missing the terminating null

Comment: This is the only one that worked for me, for some reason `c_str()` kept stopping at my null bytes even though my reading seems to indicate that it shouldn't. Maybe I did something else wrong somewhere else, but swapping `c_str()` with this (or even &str.first()) worked perfectly

Comment: i couldn't up vote this answer, because,  not worked if  (modified char array size) > (std::string instance initial size)

Comment: Why would it "work" when you wrote beyond the buffer's bounds? That applies to _any_ pointer use, @sailfish.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, i don't understand your comment, but i am saying this answer seems to be not right answer. even it is harmful. orlp's answer is enough for me.

Comment: @sailfish009 And I'm saying that your statement has nothing to do with this answer and does not make it wrong in any way.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, i think we need a talk. we are different. you insist it, but i don't agree.

Comment: @sailfish009 Let's agree to disagree then.

Comment: This will work until str goes out of scope: 
```
char *cstr = nullptr; 
{
   string str = "some string" ; 
   cstr = &str[0]; 
} 
std::cout<<cstr; // Error bad pointer since string destructed
```

Comment: @HolyBlackCat The OP asked for a non-const pointer. `&str[0]` does work on empty strings exactly like `.c_str()` does, only it is a non-const pointer

Comment: Yep, I stand corrected. Was sure that `str[0]` would count as UB out-of-bounds access, but apparently it doesn't since C++11.

Answer (score 50):

If I'd need a mutable raw copy of a c++'s string contents, then I'd do this:

```
std::string str = "string";
char* chr = strdup(str.c_str());
```

and later:

```
free(chr);
```

So why don't I fiddle with std::vector or new[] like anyone else? Because *when I need a mutable C-style raw char* string, then because I want to call C code which changes the string and C code deallocates stuff with free() and allocates with malloc() (strdup uses malloc)*. So if I pass my raw string to some function X *written in C* it *might* have a constraint on it's argument that it has to allocated on the heap (for example if the function might want to call realloc on the parameter). But it is highly unlikely that it would expect an argument allocated with (some user-redefined) new[]!

Comment: You should explain where `strdup` is from.

Answer (score 25):

<sub>(This answer applies to C++98 only.)</sub>

Please, don't use a raw `char*`.

```
std::string str = "string";
std::vector<char> chars(str.c_str(), str.c_str() + str.size() + 1u);
// use &chars[0] as a char*
```

Comment: I actually just needed something like this earlier today. I was wondering, is it OK to say `vector<char>(str.c_str(), str.c_str() + str.size() + 1)`, without assigning the char pointer to a temporary?

Comment: @Kerrek : Yes, the return value of `std::basic_string<>::c_str()` is valid until the `string` is changed or destroyed. This also implies that it returns the same value on subsequent calls as long as the `string` isn't modified.

Comment: I could (partially) agree with statement that std::vector is more "c++'ish" way. But can you explain why would you need speed/space overheads and **code complexity** for simple string manipulating/streaming?

Comment: @friendzis : There is no speed or space overhead using `vector` in this way. And if one were to write **exception-safe** code without a RAII mechanism (i.e., using raw pointers), the code complexity would be much higher than this simple one-liner.

Comment: It's a myth that `vector` has a huge amount of overhead and complexity. If your requirement is that you have a **mutable** char array, then in fact a vector of chars is pretty much the ideal C++ wrapper. If your requirement actually just calls for a const-char pointer, then just use `c_str()` and you're done.

Comment: @friendzis: You don't. Using the original `std::string` is free.

Comment: @ildjarn isn't it true that you could just use `char* chars=&str[0];` instead of creating a `std::vector` as an intermediary.

Comment: @bobobobo : Only in C++11; prior to that, std::string's storage was not guaranteed to be contiguous.

Comment: @ildjarn: Actually, [it basically was](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2256521/560648).

Answer (score 19):

- If you just want a C-style string representing the same content:

  ```
  char const* ca = str.c_str();
  ```
- If you want a C-style string with *new* contents, one way (given that you don't know the string size at compile-time) is dynamic allocation:

  ```
  char* ca = new char[str.size()+1];
  std::copy(str.begin(), str.end(), ca);
  ca[str.size()] = '\0';
  ```

  Don't forget to `delete[]` it later.
- If you want a statically-allocated, limited-length array instead:

  ```
  size_t const MAX = 80; // maximum number of chars
  char ca[MAX] = {};
  std::copy(str.begin(), (str.size() >= MAX ? str.begin() + MAX : str.end()), ca);
  ```

`std::string` doesn't implicitly convert to these types for the simple reason that needing to do this is usually a design smell. Make sure that you *really* need it.

If you **definitely** need a `char*`, the *best* way is probably:

```
vector<char> v(str.begin(), str.end());
char* ca = &v[0]; // pointer to start of vector
```

Comment: Why `&str.front(), &str.back()` (which aren't present in C++03) instead of the more common `str.begin()` and `str.end()`?

Comment: what about `str.begin()`, or even `std::begin(str)`, iterator-like?  I don't believe `string` has any obligation to be in contiguous memory like `vector`, or has it?

Comment: @xtofl: I already edited those in. And yes, as of C++11 there is an obligation; this was implicit in C++03.

Comment: @xtofl: Not in C++03. In C++11 we have that guarantee, along with the front() and back() functions, which were misused in the original answer anyway

Comment: @Armen: Not "misused" in any way. We're on C++11 now, but I edited the answer anyway. And even in C++03, it is impossible for `std::string` to _not_ be contiguous; that this wasn't explicitly stated was a bug that was fixed in C++11's wording, but the fundamental semantics of the container didn't suddenly change, trust me. FYI, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2256160/how-bad-is-code-using-stdbasic-stringt-as-a-contiguous-buffer.

Comment: @Tomalak: They were misused in that you needed `&back() + 1`, not `&back()`

Comment: @Armen: Ah, well that's true. :) You didn't mention that before. This is still the most comprehensive answer, and as of 5 minutes ago it is correct....

Comment: @Tomalak: I haven't downvoted you anyway, so I guess that doesn't matter :)

Comment: @Armen: I guess not! I'd like to know who did, and ask them to reconsider.

Comment: What about the much shorter and, even more important, much more concise and direct `vector<char> v(str.begin(), str.end())` than all this create resize and copy madness in your last example?

Comment: in the last example char* will not be null terminated. You would need to push back a null character into the vector first.

Comment: @EricRoller: If you need it to be null terminated yes

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit speaking of contiguous memory, I'm not sure which C++03 rule would have required it. Perhaps there was a O(1) complexity requirement in there. But earlier than that I know it wasn't required because for funsies I had implemented a string-compatible class based on `std::deque` which converted to a `std::vector` only when `c_str()` was called. Then it deleted that vector whenever another write operation happened. It was a good debugging tool! Surprising how many people forget about pointer invalidation requirements!

Answer (score 13):

This would be better as a comment on bobobobo's answer, but I don't have the rep for that. It accomplishes the same thing but with better practices.

Although the other answers are useful, if you ever need to convert `std::string` to `char*` explicitly without const, `const_cast` is your friend.

```
std::string str = "string";
char* chr = const_cast<char*>(str.c_str());
```

Note that this will **not** give you a copy of the data; it will give you a pointer to the string. Thus, if you modify an element of `chr`, you'll modify `str`.

Comment: There's probably a good reason the API designers made the returned pointer `const char*` and not just `char *`. `const` says "don't modify this object." When you use `const_cast`, you are saying "I know better, I really can modify the object." Or, you are saying "I __won't__ modify the object, I just need to pass it through this function that could have declared its input `const` but didn't. Although it seems safe to just throw away the `const`ness of the C-string, because we know it's mutable data underneath, you really _shouldn't_. You should avoid use of `const_cast` when you can.

Comment: Correct. Sometimes, you *have* to interface with an older API and don't have the luxury of rewriting the whole thing to be "clean and pure". Since on my VS the std::string.data () returns const char*, removing const-ness for few older methods (that have been production tested long before std::string was a thing) is definitely a right thing to do. For my situation.

Answer (score 9):

To obtain a `const char *` from an `std::string` use the [`c_str()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) member function :

```
std::string str = "string";
const char* chr = str.c_str();
```

To obtain a non-const `char *` from an `std::string` you can use the [`data()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/data) member function which returns a non-const pointer since C++17 :

```
std::string str = "string";
char* chr = str.data();
```

For older versions of the language, you can use range construction to copy the string into a vector from which a non-const pointer can be obtained :

```
std::string str = "string";
std::vector<char> str_copy(str.c_str(), str.c_str() + str.size() + 1);
char* chr = str_copy.data();
```

But beware that this won't let you modify the string contained in `str`, only the copy's data can be changed this way. Note that it's specially important in older versions of the language to use `c_str()` here because back then `std::string` wasn't guaranteed to be null terminated until `c_str()` was called.

Answer (score 8):

Assuming you just need a C-style string to pass as input:

```
std::string str = "string";
const char* chr = str.c_str();
```

Answer (score 5):

To be strictly pedantic, you cannot "convert a std::string into a char* or char[] data type."

As the other answers have shown, you can copy the content of the std::string to a char array, or make a const char* to the content of the std::string so that you can access it in a "C style".

If you're trying to change the content of the std::string, the std::string type has all of the methods to do anything you could possibly need to do to it.

If you're trying to pass it to some function which takes a char*, there's std::string::c_str().

Comment: Incorrect. If you need to pass it to some older API function that requires char*, then *c_str()* won't work because that returns const char *.

Answer (score 5):

Here is one more robust version from `Protocol Buffer`

```
char* string_as_array(string* str)
{
    return str->empty() ? NULL : &*str->begin();
}

// test codes
std::string mystr("you are here");
char* pstr = string_as_array(&mystr);
cout << pstr << endl; // you are here
```

Comment: +1 for checking that the string is empty. I would also add a check to make sure that the string is zero terminated:  `if (str[str.length()-1] != 0)  str.push_back(0)`

Answer (score 5):

Conversion in OOP style

*converter.hpp*

```
class StringConverter {
    public: static char * strToChar(std::string str);
};
```

*converter.cpp*

```
char * StringConverter::strToChar(std::string str)
{
    return (char*)str.c_str();
}
```

usage

```
StringConverter::strToChar("converted string")
```

Comment: I like how the cast to char* eliminates the const from the output of c_str, I think the reason c_str returns const char* is to eliminate potential memory access issues, by providing a read only version of the thing. the OP wants to have a char*, but I think he might be better served by const char* output of c_str instead, since that is safer, and functions that take char* usually take const char* as well (assuming functions don't do anything like changing their inputs, which in general, they shouldn't).

Comment: @FelipeValdes Never, if at all avoidable, cast away the `consteness` of an object. And if you **really** have to, use `const_cast`.

Answer (score 4):

For completeness' sake, don't forget `std::string::copy()`.

```
std::string str = "string";
const size_t MAX = 80;
char chrs[MAX];

str.copy(chrs, MAX);
```

`std::string::copy()` doesn't NUL terminate. If you need to ensure a NUL terminator for use in C string functions:

```
std::string str = "string";
const size_t MAX = 80;
char chrs[MAX];

memset(chrs, '\0', MAX);
str.copy(chrs, MAX-1);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can make it using iterator.

```
std::string str = "string";
std::string::iterator p=str.begin();
char* chr = &(*p);
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 4):

A safe version of orlp's char* answer using unique_ptr:

```
std::string str = "string";
auto cstr = std::make_unique<char[]>(str.length() + 1);
strcpy(cstr.get(), str.c_str());
```

Answer (score 3):

```
char* result = strcpy((char*)malloc(str.length()+1), str.c_str());
```

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively , you can use vectors to get a writable char* as demonstrated below;

```
//this handles memory manipulations and is more convenient
string str;
vector <char> writable (str.begin (), str.end) ;
writable .push_back ('\0'); 
char* cstring = &writable[0] //or &*writable.begin () 

//Goodluck
```

Comment: This will allocate new memory for the vector and then copy each character. std::string is already a container, you might as well push_back(0) to your string and do &str[0]

Answer (score 2):

This will also work

```
std::string s;
std::cout<<"Enter the String";
std::getline(std::cin, s);
char *a=new char[s.size()+1];
a[s.size()]=0;
memcpy(a,s.c_str(),s.size());
std::cout<<a;
```

Answer (score -1):

No body ever mentioned sprintf?

```
std::string s;
char * c;
sprintf(c, "%s", s.c_str());
```

Comment: As-is, this will cause a segmentation fault. You need to allocate memory for the char array before calling sprintf, either on the stack or heap. Easiest thing to do would be to use the length of the string to dictate the size of the char array.

Answer (score -1):

This will also work:

```
std::string s = "some string here";
char s_cstr[s.length() + 1];
strcpy(s_cstr, s.c_str();
```

Actually when I don't want to use any pointer, I'm using this method. It's using memory from stack.

No malloc, yes happiness.

Comment: Variable-length arrays are not in standard C++, and MSVC doesn't support them.

Comment: In this way, I should add the version of the compiler. My GCC version is 12.2.0, i guess v10+ GCC standards support variable-length array.

Comment: "GCC standards" isn't a thing. The standard is [a big document](http://eel.is/c++draft/) which the compilers "try" to conform to. (There's a single standard, it's not specific to each compiler, whatever that would mean.) But the compilers will usually accept all kinds of non-standard crap with default settings. If you add `-std=c++23 -pedantic-errors` to compiler flags, it'll start rejecting this as it should.

Comment: There's little reason to use this non-standard construct when you can directly get a pointer from a string using `s.data()`, as the second most upvoted answer here suggests.

Comment: Thanks for your informations! Sorry for my fault.