# Giving apostrophe as a case of switch

Tags: c, switch-statement, apostrophe

My code:

```
char function [100];  
switch (function [i]) {  
    case '+' : {  
    } break;  
    case '*': {  
    }break;  
    case '\'' :{  
    }break;  
    default: {  
          printf ("argument %c not recognized \n", function [i]);  
          return 1;  
        }  
} return 0;
```

I'm executing program with:
    `./a.out "AB+A'*"`
but everything what I see is that apostrophe is not recognized. How I should write this switch case? Of course I can't give
    `./a.out "AB+A\'*"`   - \ not recognized
and 
    `./a.out AB+A\'*`     - ' not recognized

Comment: Your code looks like it would recognize a single quote ok. I'd suggest adding some print statements in your main. Or post more code.

Comment: [Did you miss something](http://ideone.com/mrPuiM) ?

Comment: Are you sure you entered `'`  and not `´`  or `\``?

Comment: ASCII code says it's 39 so its apostrophe

Comment: So the binary program showing you any results is not based on the sources you show. Are you sure you did recompile the correct sources? Recompile with debug info/symbols (option `-g` for gcc) and run your program in a debugger (gdb) tracing it step by step and inspecting the values of the relevant variables.

Comment: yes, I chceked it a lot of times

Comment: You did run the program using a debugger? If not, this is the perfect opportunity to learn it ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a break

```
    case '\'': {
      if (wskaznikStosu < 1) {
        printf ("\nZa dużo operandów \n");
        return 1;}
      else {
      int a = stos [wskaznikStosu - 1];
      wskaznikStosu --;
      stos [wskaznikStosu] = not (a);
      wskaznikStosu ++;
      }
    }
    // YOU ARE MISSING A BREAK HERE AND FALLING INTO THE DEFAULT
    default: {
```

Comment: Before I fill function with  strcpy(function, argv[1])  could it be a problem?

Comment: That won't cause the problem. Perhaps you are confusing ' with ` or some other ascii character? print out each char with %d, then look at an ascii table.

Comment: 39 is a single quote so your code should work. Maybe post your entire function and your main.

Comment: See my edit, you are missing a break and falling into the default.

Answer (score 1):

I have watched answers and all you need to do is read the post:

[How to convert string to char array in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13294067/how-to-convert-string-to-char-array-in-c)

and use code in Artur's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did. It seems to work :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int i;

  if (argc != 3)
    {
      fprintf (stderr, "argument error\n");
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

  for (i = 0; i < atoi(argv[2]); ++i) {
    switch (argv[1][i]) {  
    case '+' :
      printf ("+\n");
      break;  
    case '*':
      printf ("*\n");
      break;  
    case '\'' :
      printf ("'\n");
      break;
    default:
      printf ("argument %c not recognized \n", argv[1][i]);
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
  }


  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should consider removing the braces in your case statements and use instructions as I did maybe it is the source of your problem.

Comment: Ok my bad it's just that I have never seen that in C programming :)