# Return pointer from the library to app

Tags: c++, pointers, output

So, i have a lib file where i have function which converts string to char* :

```
void Additional::str2Char(string s,char** cstr)
{
    *cstr = new char[s.length() + 1];
    *cstr = (char*) s.c_str();
}
```

Then, i create console app, and do this:

```
int main()
{
    Additional *a = new Additional();
    string b = "fdfd";
    char *test;
    a->str2Char(b, &test);
    cout << test << endl;
    delete a;
}
```

The ouput is really bad..
Help me, i dont know how to get the pointer from lib right.

Comment: You are referencing the data of a local string `s`. That reference becomes invalid outside of the function. Also, why are you dynamically allocating `a`?

Comment: @juanchopanza i pass the string to this funciton not vice versa. Dont worry about "a", i think its not a problem. If a local - i have same problem.

Comment: and how it is related to `C`?

Comment: `s` is a local variable in the function. On top of that, you never copy its data to the buffer you allocate. So you have a dangling pointer *and* a memory leak.

Comment: @mrglut - Even though you say "don't worry about 'a'", it gives an insight on how you're approaching your issue.  Perception means a lot...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you allocate some memory.

Then you reassign the pointer to that memory, to point to the contents of the local string `s`, leaking the memory you allocated.

Then you return from the function, destroying `s`, leaving the pointer dangling. It no longer points to valid data, and dereferencing it gives undefined behaviour.

The best solution is to stop messing around with pointers and `new`, and use `std::string` for all your strings. If you really want to do this, then you'll need to copy the string contents to the new memory:

```
*cstr = new char[s.length() + 1]; // no change
std::strcpy(*cstr, s.c_str());    // copy the data, including the terminator
```

Answer (score 0):

If the library is not going to modify the text then, the `c_str()` call is enough. No need to create an char pointer/array.

If it is going to modify the text: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13294114/47351

```
strncpy(tab2, tmp.c_str(), sizeof(tab2));
tab2[sizeof(tab2) - 1] = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to handle the memory allocation inside the function, a different API could be used:

```
// Creates a const char* and copies the contents of s to it. Caller
// takes ownership of the returned data.
const char* str2cstr(const string& s) {
    char* cstr = new char[s.size()];
    strncopy(cstr, s.c_str(), s.size());
    return cstr;
}
```

Now you can do `const char* cstr = str2cstr(str);`. Notice also that I'm using a `const string&` param to avoid the extra string copy.

Comment: Thx, really good thing!
But now, i prefer the first solution, it is good too;)