# cout char array gives mixed results

Tags: c++

The following code prints the expected output within the for loop , but once I exit the loop , it only prints "Here" , with nothing underneath it. What am I missing here?

```
char ** strs = new char*[n];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    string str;
    getline(cin, str);
    strs[i] = const_cast<char*>(str.c_str());
    cout << strs[i] << endl;
}
cout  <<"here" <<strs[1] << endl;
```

Comment: Ahmed could you please explain the thought processes that led to your design decisions here?

Comment: This is only a piece of the code. throughout the code I call a function that requires passing a char array , I didn't want to use the casting multiple times.

Comment: @AhmedElyamani: Please explain the thought processes that led to your design decisions here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Your pointers are dangling.**

You've stored pointers to the data buffer of a `std::string`. That buffer ceases to exist on each new iteration, to be replaced by the buffer of the next iteration's version of `str`; furthermore, there is absolutely no trace of it after the loop ends.

Don't do this. Just store `std::string`s.

That `const_cast` is completely ill-advised too. Not sure why you're doing it.

Comment: I'm trying to read an input string then cast it into an array of chars to call some other function. That const_cast was what I found here on SO

Comment: @AhmedElyamani Store the strings and call the other function with str.c_str(). You will spend less time debugging. If you need to call the other function with a char *, either change the other function to take string & or const char * or copy str.c_str to your own buffer that you can safely pass to the other function. Don't cast const to non-const. You get all sorts of crashes and weird errors when you attempt to write into constant data.

Comment: @AhmedElyamani: Please point us to the answer that advised such a `const_cast`, so that we may downvote it and prevent anyone else from falling into the trap.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It was submitted as part of this question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13294067/how-to-convert-string-to-char-array-in-c
Then again , I'm only a few days into c++. I probably misinterpreted something there.

Comment: @AhmedElyamani: It's not generally advisable to copy/paste code from _questions_, when the question was posted for the express reason that **the code didn't work** (and, yes, that code there is awful!). Take inspiration from _answers_, instead, and even then only when you understand them and know _why_ you're absorbing the solution into your own code.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit You are right. It's just that coming from javascript I was trying to solve a specific problem in c++ and all these type castings were the last of my worries , so I rushed to copying what seemed to be a straightforward approach , but turned out not to be.

Answer (score 4):

> What am I missing here?

In theory, you are seeing the symptoms of undefined behavior.

You are storing the a pointer to the data held by `str` in `strs[i]` but `str` is deleted when you get out of the `for` loop. The pointer is not valid after the end of the loop.

In practice, you are seeing only the last value read since every element of `strs` stores the same pointer value.

You can avoid problems by using standard containers.

```
std::vector<std::string>> strs;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    string str;
    getline(cin, str);
    strs.push_back(str);
    cout << strs[i] << endl;
}
```

Comment: It's not the address of `str`.