# Conversion from an array of strings to an array of characters

Tags: c++, arrays

I have an array of strings and I want to use the elements of that array as the argument of a function, but the argument of my function should be `char*` type.

How can I solve this problem?

```
string Arr[]={"aa.txt","bb.txt","cc.txt"};
void myfunc(char* Arr[i]);
```

I am programming in visual studio C++ 2010.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert string to char array in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13294067/how-to-convert-string-to-char-array-in-c)

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I recommend changing the parameter type to a `vector` of `string`.  The function parameter is a pointer to a **single** character.  You could also change the parameter to `std::string`.  You should think twice about converting between `std::string` and `char *`.  Always prefer the `string`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `std::string::c_str()`, but the function argument would need to be const. Otherwise, I think your only option is to alloc a copy of the returned `const char* std::string::c_str()`.