# Array will be given value and size during run time

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I am trying to make a program which declares an array(string) which will gain its size and value during the run time , user will input them.
This is a code , but it fails giving error: initializer failed to determine size of text.

```
string txt;
int x;
cout << "Enter the text\n";
cin >>   txt;
char text[] = txt;
x = sizeof(text[]);
cout << x;
return 0;
```

This is another one, it gives error: storage size of text isn`t known.

```
 char text[];
 int x;
cout << "Enter the text\n";
cin >>   text;
 x = sizeof(text[]);
cout << x;
  return 0;
```

Comment: sorry the title was supposed to be , Array will be given value and size during run time

Comment: What you really want is a [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string)

Comment: @MohamedKhaled You can [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/37706418/edit) your question to make any necessary changes (e.g., Fix the title)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better use the `string` type. Then you can call the method `size()` for that string.

```
string txt;
int x;
cout << "Enter the text\n";
cin >>   txt;
x = txt.size();
cout << x;
return 0;
```

Comment: it`s ok but i need , the array . now iam stucked here                                                char text[x] = txt; , it gives , error; array must be initialized with  a brace-enclosed initializer

Comment: For simple questions like this please "google" it
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13294067/how-to-convert-string-to-char-array-in-c

Answer (score 0):

```
char text[] = txt;
```

is wrong.

You can't cast a `std::string` type to a `char[]` array straight away.

If you want to access the raw pointer to the `char[]` array maintained within the `std::string`, use the [`std::string::c_str()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) or [`std::string::data()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/data) member functions.

---

I actually don't get what kind of capers you're doing with `char[]`, but I'd rewrite your code simply like this:

```
string txt;
int x;
cout << "Enter the text\n";
cin >>   txt;
// char text[] = txt; <<<<< remove
x = txt.size(); // <<<<<< change
cout << x;
return 0;
```

If there's further need for `[const] char*` types, you can use the functions as mentioned in the 1st part of my answer.

Comment: can you write example

Comment: @MohamedKhaled For what actually?

Comment: i mean , if you can write me the code line to solve the problem , i didnt get what you mean in the answer

Answer (score 0):

ok , i`ve found it

```
string txt;
int x;
cout << "Enter the text\n";
getline  (cin,txt);
x = txt.size();
 char text[x];
strcat(text,txt.c_str());
cout <<"string="<<txt<<endl;
for (i=0;i<=x;i++){
    cout << "text["<<i<<"] : "<<text[i]<<endl;
}
return 0;
```