# string size limit input cin.get() and getline()

Tags: c++11, input, user-input, cin, getline

In this project the user can type in a text(**maximum 140 characters**).
so for this limitation I once used `getline()`:

```
  string text;
  getline(cin, text);
  text = text.substr(1, 140);
```

but in this case the result of `cout << text << endl;` is an empty string.

so I used `cin.get()` like:

```
cin.get(text, 140);
```

this time I get this error: no matching function for call to ‘std::basic_istream::get(std::__cxx11::string&, int)’

note that I have included `<iostream>`

so the question is how can I fix this why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

Your first approach is sound with one correction - you need to use

```
text = text.substr(0, 140);
```

instead of `text = text.substr(1, 140);`. Containers (which includes a string) in C/C++ start with index 0 and you are requesting the string to be trimmed from position 1. This is perfectly fine, but if the string happens to be only one character long, calling `text.substr(1, 140);` will not necessarily cause the program to crash, but will not end up in the desired output either.

According to [this source](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr), `substr` will throw an out of range exception if called with starting position larger than string length. In case of a one character string, position 1 would be equal to string length, but the return value is not meaningful (in fact, it may even be an undefined behavior but I cannot find a confirmation of this statement - in yours and my case, calling it returns an empty string). I recommend you test it yourself in the interactive coding section following the link above.

Your second approach tried to pass a string to a function that expected C-style character arrays. Again, more can be found [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get). Like the error said, the compiler couldn't find a matching function because the argument was a string and not the char array. Some functions will perform a conversion of string to char, but this is not the case here. You could convert the string to char array yourself, as for instance described [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13294067/how-to-convert-string-to-char-array-in-c), but the first approach is much more in line with C++ practices.

Last note - currently you're only reading a single line of input, I assume you will want to change that.