# C++ Making specific char from string

Tags: c++, string, multidimensional-array, char

I dont know how to call it, I think its multidimensional char string.
My problem is:
I have this:

```
string serialnumber = "123456";
```

And I want to make this using code

```
char tmp6[] = { '1','2','3','4','5','6', 0 };
```

Comment: But why? You probably just need `serialnumber.c_str()`. => https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert string to char array in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13294067/how-to-convert-string-to-char-array-in-c)

Answer (score -2):

// assigning value to string s 
    string s = "geeksforgeeks";

```
int n = s.length(); 

// declaring character array 
char char_array[n + 1]; 

// copying the contents of the 
// string to char array 
strcpy(char_array, s.c_str());
```

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/convert-string-char-array-cpp/

Comment: Not legal C++ even if it is on the geeks for geeks web site. In C++ array bounds must be compile time constants, but in your code `n` is a variable.

Comment: Geeksforgeeks teaches such horrible practices. Not every compiler will eat `char char_array[n + 1];` it's non-standard. Also there is no need to copy anything at all. `s.c_str()` returns the required C-style-string.

Comment: What about this link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13294067/how-to-convert-string-to-char-array-in-c

Comment: Simplest way I can think of doing it is:

string temp = "cat";
char tab2[1024];
strcpy(tab2, temp.c_str());
For safety, you might prefer:

string temp = "cat";
char tab2[1024];
strncpy(tab2, temp.c_str(), sizeof(tab2));
tab2[sizeof(tab2) - 1] = 0;
or could be in this fashion:

string temp = "cat";
char * tab2 = new char [temp.length()+1];
strcpy (tab2, temp.c_str());

Comment: I raised this question as duplicate