# Different value when converting char*

Tags: c++, char, constants

I have to convert `token[1]` to `vm_address_t`, but when doing so the original value is lost. Any idea how to convert / cast it right ?

Here is my code:

```
char* ConvertToC(string value){
    char *cvalue = &value[0u];
    return cvalue;
} 

const char* getOffsetToken(string value){
    const char *offsettoken;
    int n = 0;

    const char* token[4] = {};

    token[0] = strtok(ConvertToC(value), " ");
    if (token[0]) {
        for (n = 1; n < 4; n++) {
            token[n] = strtok(0, " ");
            if (!token[n]) break;
        }
    }
    offsettoken=token[1];
    return offsettoken;
}

int main(){
    vm_address_t vmp;
    const char* cp;
    string p1 = "1 0x1000 2 0x0120";

    cout << getOffsetToken(p1)<<endl;
    cp=getOffsetToken(p1);
    cout << cp<<endl;
    vmp<<(vm_address_t)cp;
    cout << vmp<<endl;
}
```

The output is:

```
0x10 ?
0x1000
140734705163168
```

Comment: There is a `string::c_str` function and you should probably use it instead of yours `ConvertToC`

Comment: We have no idea what these types are, bub..

Comment: @Spo1ler can't use c_str because it returns a const char* i need a char* , found this http://stackoverflow.com/a/16502000/3452589 thats why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
 char* ConvertToC(string value){
```

should be a reference parameter

```
 char* ConvertToC(string& value){
                     // ^
```

Otherwise the address returned refers to a temporary copy and turns invalid after the function call.

Comment: Thanks for this ! It solved first line's code. Now output is :
     0x1000
     0x1000
     140734590696352

Comment: @user3452589 I'd recommend you inspect your code using a debugger 1st, before asking here. I'm not one.