# How do I convert xor encryption from using std::string to just char or char *?

Tags: c++, string, char, xor

So essentially with the libraries that i'm working with I cannot use std::string, as it uses a somewhat depreciated version of C++ I need to convert this xor function from using std::string to just using char or char *. I have been trying but I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong, as I get an error. Here is the code:

```
string encryptDecrypt(string toEncrypt) {
    char key[] = "DSIHKGDSHIGOK$%#%45434etG34th8349ty"; //Any chars will work
    string output = toEncrypt;

    for (int i = 0; i < toEncrypt.size(); i++)
        output[i] = toEncrypt[i] ^ key[i % (sizeof(key) / sizeof(char))];

    return output;
}
```

If anyone could help me out, that would be great. I am unsure as to why I cannot do it by simply changing the strings to char *.

Edit:

What I have tried is:

```
char * encryptDecrypt(char * toEncrypt) {
    char key[] = "DSIHKGDSHIGOK$%#%45434etG34th8349ty"; //Any chars will work 
    char * output = toEncrypt; 
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(toEncrypt); i++) 
        output[i] = toEncrypt[i] ^ key[i % (sizeof(key) / sizeof(char))]; 
    return output; 
}
```

Please note I am not trying to convert an std::string to char, I simply cannot use std::string in any instance of this function. Therefore, my question is not answered. Please read my question more carefully before marking it answered...

Comment: what version of c++ are you using that doesn't have `std::string`?  Can you post what you have tried?

Comment: Nathan, I am using an sdk for a platform that has the string headers but does not allow you to use them. If you try to use them on execute the thread will not be created. Its weird. and here is the that I tried:
`code`char * encryptDecrypt(char * toEncrypt) {
 char key[] = "DSIHKGDSHIGOK$%#%45434etG34th8349ty"; //Any chars will work
 char * output = toEncrypt;

 for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(toEncrypt); i++)
  output[i] = toEncrypt[i] ^ key[i % (sizeof(key) / sizeof(char))];

 return output;
}`code`
Sorry about the formatting, I am unsure of how to place code in a comment.

Comment: Previously asked and answered in http://stackoverflow.com/a/7352131/227103

Comment: Possible duplicate of [std::string to char\*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7352099/stdstring-to-char)

Comment: @YuppieNetworking no, not a duplicate. The question is how to write the same function using only C strings in place of `std::string`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is

```
char * output = toEncrypt;
```

This is making `output` point to `toEncrypt` which is not what you want to do.  What you need to do is allocate a new `char*` and then copy the contents of `toEncrypt` into `output`

```
char * encryptDecrypt(char * toEncrypt) {
    char key[] = "DSIHKGDSHIGOK$%#%45434etG34th8349ty"; //Any chars will work 
    int string_size = std::strlen(toEncrypt); 
    char * output = new char[string_size + 1]; // add one for the null byte
    std::strcpy(output, toEncrypt); //copy toEncrypt into output
    for (int i = 0; i < string_size; i++) 
        output[i] = toEncrypt[i] ^ key[i % (sizeof(key) / sizeof(char))]; 
    return output; 
}
```

<kbd>[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5f8c20469ae39865)</kbd>

Since we are using dynamic memory allocation here we need to make sure that the caller deletes the memory when done otherwise it will be a memory leak.

Comment: Thank you! This works, but the only thing is it does not encrypt the entire string for some weird reason. Only the first 3 or 4 characters.

Comment: `sizeof(toEncrypt)` should be `strlen` to get length of the string in characters.

Comment: If it's not working past the first few characters, it's likely that your input arguments contain the null byte.  Therefore, `strlen` will NOT work for your purposes.  Check my answer for a solution.

Comment: @AbsoluteZero Updated answer to fix that

Comment: Ah, didn't notice that you hadn't updated the `sizeof`.  That'd explain the partial encryption.  I'd still recommend avoiding `strlen` if possible, depending on the requirements of possible input / output strings.

Comment: @JackO'Reilly True.  I would pass the size of the string but I didn't want to change the prototype on the OP so `strlen` it is.

Comment: It still has partial encryption. This along with Jack's answer fixed one part of it, but now it does not return the correct decrypted string.

Comment: @AbsoluteZero It is working in this live example: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5f8c20469ae39865

Answer (score 2):

sizeof() is a compile-time operator that evaluates the size of the type of its argument.  When you do `sizeof(toEncrypt)`, you're really just doing `sizeof(char*)` -- not the length of the string, which is what you want.  You'll need to somehow indicate how long the `toEncrypt` string is.  Here are two possible solutions:

1. Add an integer argument to `encryptDecrypt` specifying the length of `toEncrypt` in characters.
2. If you know that `toEncrypt` will never contain the null byte as a valid character for encryption / decryption (not sure of your application) and can assume that `toEncrypt` is null-terminated, you could use the `strlen` function to determine string length at runtime.

I'd recommend option 1, as `strlen` can introduce security holes if you're not careful, and also because it allows the use of null bytes within your string arguments.

Comment: This fixed my error of only encrypting part of it, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

What error are you getting?  You can easily use a char* to do the same thing, I've included a sample program that verifies the functionality.  This was built under VS2012.

```
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>

std::string encryptDecrypt( std::string toEncrypt)
{
    char key[] = "DSIHKGDSHIGOK$%#%45434etG34th8349ty"; //Any chars will work
    std::string output = toEncrypt;

    for (int i = 0; i < toEncrypt.size(); i++)
        output[i] = toEncrypt[i] ^ key[i % (sizeof(key) / sizeof(char))];

    return output;
}

void encryptDecrypt( char* toEncrypt )
{
    char key[] = "DSIHKGDSHIGOK$%#%45434etG34th8349ty"; //Any chars will work
    int len = strlen( toEncrypt );

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        toEncrypt[i] = toEncrypt[i] ^ key[i % (sizeof(key) / sizeof(char))];
}

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    const char* sample = "This is a sample string to process";
    int len = strlen( sample );
    char* p = new char[ len + 1 ];
    p[len] = '\0';
    strcpy( p, sample );

    std::string output = encryptDecrypt( sample );
    encryptDecrypt( p );

    bool match = strcmp(output.c_str(), p) == 0;
    printf( "The two encryption functions %smatch.\n", match ? "" : "do not "   );

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Why not instead of string output = toEncrypt :

```
char *output = new char[std::strlen(toEncrypt) + 1];
std::strcpy(output, toEncrypt);
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot the strcpy part.