# Switch statement will NOT print a string

Tags: c++

```
char gamerCentral::getGamerTag( )
{
    switch(gamerTag)
            {

        case '1':  return gamerTag = "Diamond";  
                    break; 
        case '2':  return  gamerTag = "Silver";
                    break; 
        case '3':  return  gamerTag = "Bronze";
                    break; 
        case '4':  return  gamerTag = "Wood";
                    break;    
        default:   return  gamerTag = "Uninstall";

        break; 
            }

 char   gamerTag;

GamerClub::GamerClub(
        char tag)
    {
    gamerTag = tag;


}
```

I'm trying to return the gamerTag, but it says that it cannot convert to a string. Is their a way to convert the char to a string inside the switch statement?

Comment: Seems like [The XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Why not use string type to store the strings?

Comment: You should change the signature of your function. A char is a char, you need something bigger than a `char` here. Closest would be a `const  char *`, you can have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7352099/stdstring-to-char) if you want to see more.

Comment: How do you expect to be able to assign an entire string to a mere, lowly, `char` variable?

Comment: What is going on in this code? You're assigning a `const char*` to a `char`, then returning the result of that assignment?

Comment: Do NOT do this: `#define char std::string`

Comment: Its needed to be a char and needs to return as a string for the output of the user. The project is required to input a single input "char" and output the string. Is there anyway I can get the input to be a char and output the message for example "Diamond" a different way?

Comment: 1. you're not printing.  2. no need to break after a return, it just makes things longer   3.  `std::string getGamerTag(char tag)`   4.  
`std::string tag = getGamerTag(gamerTag)`  5.  `cout << tag`

Answer (score 3):

Have your function return a string, it can still operate on the single character as input.  Here's an example.

```
std::string getGamerTag(char t)
{
   switch(t)
   {
      case '1': return "Diamond";
      case '2': return "Silver";
      // ...
   }

   return "";
}

// prints "Silver"
cout << getGamerTag('2');
```

Comment: string gamerCentral::getGamerTag(char gamerTag )
{
    switch(gamerTag)
            {

        case '1':  return gamerTag = "Diamond";  
        case '2':  return  gamerTag = "Silver";
        case '3':  return  gamerTag = "Bronze";
        case '4':  return  gamerTag = "Wood";
        default:   return  gamerTag = "Uninstall";
            }

Comment: This is what i'm putting and it still will not convert.

Comment: `return gamerTag = "Diamond";` _is_ what is wrong.  You can't assign the value "Diamond" to a `char`.  Look more closely at my answer.

Answer (score 0):

use string variable or use char*

```
char* getGamerTag(int t)
{
   switch(t)
   {
      case 1: return "Diamond";
      case 2: return "Silver";
   }
}
int main()
{
    cout << getGamerTag(2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using an array of strings:

```
std::string getGamerTag(unsigned int t)
{
  static const char * tag_names[] =
  {
    "Diamond", "Silver", "Bronze", "Wood", "Unistall",
  };
  static const unsigned int name_quantity =
    sizeof(tag_names) / sizeof(tag_names[0]);

  std::string name;
  if ((t > 0) && (t <= name_quantity))
  {
    name = tag_names[t - 1];
  }
  return name;
}
```