# String transfer

Tags: swift, string, objective-c++

I'd like to return a `String` back to Swift using this code:

**MyFile.h**:

```
+ (char *) myCoolCode;
```

**MyFile.mm**:

```
+(string)myCoolCode {
   string myCoolString = "";
   myCoolString += "123";
   return myCoolString;
}
```

**MyFile.swift**:

```
let superCoolString = MyBridge.myCoolCode()
print(superCoolString)
```

But obviously it doesn't seems working the right way because it's crashing somewhere deep inside.

[image: See this image]

Comment: Assuming your `string` is a C++ `std::string`, you cannot fake it to `char *` with incompatible header. Also, Swift cannot convert `char *` as Swift `String`. First convert your `myCoolString` into `NSString *` to make Swift convert it to Swift `String`.

Comment: Would you be so kind to share some code? `:)` @OOPer

Comment: Why are you defining the return value to be a `char` and in the implementation file a `string`?

Comment: Because adding "string" instead of "char *" to `MyFile.h` will not work for me so I'm getting errors there @JakubTruhlář.

Comment: @OOPer what's the problem with tempi's comment? You indicated that you know the solution but did not present it in a way that's consumable for the OP. So asking for more info seems very reasonable to me.

Comment: @dr_barto, sorry, it's my personal feelings and the comments of tempi in this thread is nothing to do with it. Seems I should delete the comment of mine. One more, please do not hesitate to write an answer if you know what is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have already pointed out in the comments you should fix the return type of your `.mm` file to `char *` and not `string`. You should always keep those two types the same. An example of your function implementation can be:

```
- (char *)myCoolCode
{
    char str[] = "foobar";
    //You can do whatever you want with str here. Just make sure it's null terminated
    return str;
}
```

Then in your swift code:

```
let myCoolString = String(cString: MyBridge.myCoolCode())
print(myCoolString)
```

Reference on the string constructor is [here.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/1641523-init)

The reason your code was crashing is probably because you were returning an instance of `std::string` which doesn't really work in Swift. You can use `std::string` but you have to convert it to `char *` when returning it. You can do so as is [shown here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7352099/stdstring-to-char)