# C++: Cannot convert string to char*?

Tags: c++, data-structures, casting, queue

I'm trying to print the first item (top item) of a `Deque` in C++ with the following piece of code:

```
#include <queue>
#include <deque>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    deque<string> commandHistory;

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        commandHistory.push_back("asdf");
    }

    printf(commandHistory.at(1));
    return 0;
}
```

However, I get an error in the printf statement:

> error: cannot convert
> ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traitsstd::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char
>
> > , std::__cxx11::basic_string >::value_type’ {aka ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string’} to ‘const char*’

However, I cannot cast `commandHistory.at(1)` to a `const char*` like so:

```
printf((const char*) commandHistory.at(1));
```

Comment: `std::cout << commandHistory.at(1);`

Comment: (std::string does offer ways access the char* value.. not that it’s necessarily appropriate here. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7352099/stdstring-to-char).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventhough your question is marked both C and C++, I'd remove the C tag since your code is more C++ than C.

The documentation for `printf` is here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf

The gist of that function is that it takes at least 1 param: the so called format string, which as the signature says, is a `const char*`.

`char *` and `std::string` are totally different types. `std::string` is a class and `char *` is just a pointer to a builtin type. Your `std::deque` contains `std::string` objects.

Conveniently, `std::string` offers a conversion function to `const char*` for exactly these cases.

A working snippet would thus be:

```cpp
// looks like you were missing cstdio
#include <cstdio>
#include <deque>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    deque<string> commandHistory;

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        commandHistory.push_back("asdf");
    }
    // note the `c_str` method call to get a c-style string from a std::string
    printf(commandHistory.at(1).c_str());
    return 0;
}
```

Like the compiler says, you can't convert (with `static_cast`) a `std::string` to a `char*`, but you can obtain that desired const char* with `.c_str()`.

As other mentioned, you could also include `iostream` and use `std::cout` which `knows` what to do (by overloading) with each type (const char*, std::string, int, ...) and can also be used with your own types.

EDIT: cleaner/clearer code/explanations.

Comment: It's generally unsafe to use `printf` this way: if the deque ever contains strings with printf format specifiers, you'll get Undefined Behaviour when the matching arguments are not provided. At least use `printf("%s", commandHistory.at(1).c_str())`.

Comment: (wanted to keep the code as close as possible to the original) still +1, I can add an edit with what you mentioned!