# Does std::string need to store its character in a contiguous piece of memory?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, language-lawyer, c++17

I know that in C++98, neither `std::basic_string<>` nor `std::vector<>` were required to use contiguous storage. This was seen as an oversight for `std::vector<>` as soon as it was pointed out, and, if I remember correctly, got fixed with C++03.

I *seem* to remember having read about discussions requiring `std::basic_string<>` to use contiguous storage back when C++11 was still called C++0x, but I haven't followed the discussion closely back then, and am still restricted to C++03 at work, so I am not sure what became of it.

So is `std::basic_string<>` required to use contiguous storage? (If so, then which version of the standard required it first?)

<sup>In case you wonder: This is important if you have code passing the result of `&str[0]` to a function expecting a contiguous piece of memory to write to. (I know about `str.data()`, but for obvious reasons old code doesn't use it.)</sup>

Comment: Well, since `str.data()` needs to be constant time and is required to return a continuous memory block, I would conclude that yes.

Comment: See similar questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986966/does-s0-point-to-contiguous-characters-in-a-stdstring and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2256160/is-it-reasonable-to-use-stdbasic-stringt-as-a-contiguous-buffer-when-targeti, which answers the question but in a way that is not trivial to read.

Comment: What are those obvious reasons for not using `data()`? That function was present in C++03 as well.

Comment: @Mr.kbok: I had seen them both, read the answer, and thought I'd rather have an up-to-date definitive answer.

Comment: I am quite sure that in C++03 the answer is no, although virtually all the implementations used contiguous memory. I'll try to find a reference for this.

Comment: @Angew: In C++03, `str.data()` returned a `const char*`.

Comment: @sbi Oh, right. I was confused by the fact that C++03 defined `[]` in terms of `data()`, even for the non-const overload!

Comment: FWIW, I've never seen or heard of a discontiguous `std::basic_string` implementation; anyone interested in that would likely have added it as a distinct [STL `rope`](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Rope.html) lookalike.  So, in practice if I were you I'd just peek at your work C++03's Standard Libraries (if paranoid) then code on the assumption it'll always be contiguous.

Comment: @sbi That doesn't really change the fact that even in C++03 it needs to be constant time and continuous.

Comment: @sbi "In C++03, `str.data()` returned a `const char*`"  Has that changed in C++11? Feel like I'm missing something...

Comment: @Let_Me_Be C++03 allowed for implementation to use two separate storages, one for `operator[]`and one for `c_str` (no idea why would any implementor do that). This still meets the constant time requirement of `c_str`. If you take a look at the page on [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) you can see that `data() + i` was not required to be equal to `&operator[](i)` in 03.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The [C++11 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf), basic_string 21.4.1.5,

> The char-like objects in a basic_string object shall be stored
>   contiguously. That is, for any basic_string object s, the identity
>   &*(s.begin() + n) == &*s.begin() + n shall hold for all values of n
>   such that 0 <= n < s.size().

Answer (score 15):

In c++03 there was no guarantee that that the elements of the string are stored continiously.  [basic.string] was

> 1. For a char-like type charT, the class template basic_string describes objects that can store a
>      sequence consisting of a varying number of arbitrary char-like objects (clause 21). The first element of the
>      sequence is at position zero. Such a sequence is also called a “string” if the given char-like type is clear
>      from context. In the rest of this clause, charT denotes such a given char-like type. Storage for the string
>      is allocated and freed as necessary by the member functions of class basic_string, via the
>      Allocator class passed as template parameter. Allocator::value_type shall be the same as
>      charT.
> 2. The class template basic_string conforms to the requirements of a Sequence, as specified in (23.1.1).
>      Additionally, because the iterators supported by basic_string are random access iterators (24.1.5),
>      basic_string conforms to the the requirements of a Reversible Container, as specified in (23.1).
>      389
>      ISO/IEC 14882:2003(E)  ISO/IEC
>      21.3 Class template basic_string 21 Strings library
> 3. In all cases, size() <= capacity().

And then in C++17 they changed it too

> 1. The class template basic_string describes objects that can store a sequence consisting of a varying number
>      of arbitrary char-like objects with the first element of the sequence at position zero. Such a sequence is also
>      called a “string” if the type of the char-like objects that it holds is clear from context. In the rest of this
>      Clause, the type of the char-like objects held in a basic_string object is designated by charT.
> 2. The member functions of basic_string use an object of the Allocator class passed as a template parameter
>      to allocate and free storage for the contained char-like objects.233
> 3. **A basic_string is a contiguous container (23.2.1).**
> 4. In all cases, size() <= capacity().

<sup>emphasis mine</sup>

So pre C++17 it was not guaranteed but now it is.

With the constraints that `std::string::data` imposes this non guarantee is almost moot as calling `std::string::data` gives you a continuous array of the characters in the string.  So unless the implementation is doing this on demand and in constant time the string will be continuous.

---

> <sup>In case you wonder: This is important if you have code passing the result of `&str[0]` to a function expecting a contiguous piece of memory to write to. (I know about `str.data()`, but for obvious reasons old code doesn't use it.)</sup>

The behavior of `operator[]` has changed as well.  In C++03 we had

> **Returns:** If pos < size(), returns data()[pos]. Otherwise, if pos == size(), the const
>   version returns charT(). Otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

So only the `const` version was guaranteed to have defined behavior if you tried `&s[0]` when `s` is empty.  In C++11 they changed it to:

> *Returns:* *(begin() + pos) if pos < size(). Otherwise, returns a reference to an object of type
>   charT with value charT(), where modifying the object leads to undefined behavior.

So now both the `const` and non `const` versions have defined behavior if you tried `&s[0]` when `s` is empty.

Comment: There is no way to have `string::data()` to be constant time function that returns a continuous sequence without the actual storage being continuous, even in C++03.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be Yes but if the standard doesn't impose the requirement then you can't be certain this will happen 100% of the time.  I am envisioning a deque like structure.

Comment: The standard imposes the requirement of `string::data()` containing the same content as the content of the string and it imposes the constant time requirement on `string::data()`. There is no way to have a deque like structure and maintain the constant time restriction.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be I added the caveat about `string::data()` into the answer.

Comment: Thanks for expanding on Rahul's answer. As an occasional visitor to C++, I have to work around popular generalisations: one of them is that pointer-based languages offer no guarantees about the physical layout of any nontrivial data structure: all that you know is that the data in the structure will transparently accessible from its pointer. *Transparently*, not 'sequentially by performing arithmetic on addresses'. Hence the earlier specification of 'conforms to... a Reversible Container' rather than 'contiguous' - And you can be sure that assuming a contiguous block has bitten someone once.

Comment: @Nathan: In the last decade I kept running into code where people passed `&s[0]` (or `&*str.begin()`) into functions requiring a pointer to the first element of a writable C char array. Usually I have left such code alone (assuming, of course, that they made sure the string isn't empty), since there never was any known implementation where string didn't have non-contiguous memory, and, as I said, I seemed to recall the intent to make this a requirement anyway. Nevertheless, I now wanted to know whether this change has finally been done. Thanks!

Comment: "Contiguous container" is not C++11. That's C++17, added by [N4284](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4284). (The other C++11 requirements do require contiguous underlying storage.)

Answer (score 2):

According to the draft standard [N4527](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2015/n4527.pdf) *21.4/3 Class template basic_string [basic.string]* :

> A basic_string is a contiguous container (23.2.1).