# Array of char using unique_ptr in this specific case

Tags: c++, c++11, unique-ptr

I am currently working on a little server using sockets in C++.

I have a function which sends string:

```
void SocketServer::SendData(int id_client, const std::string &str)
{
  int size = str.size();
  send(id_client, &size, 4, 0);
  send(id_client, str.c_str(), str.size(), 0);
}
```

First, I send 4 bytes which corresponds to the length of the string I want to send.

Then, I have a function which receives the string:

```
int SocketServer::ReceiveData(int id_client)
{
  char  buffer[1024]; // <<< this line, bad idea, I want to use unique_ptr
  int size = 0;
  int ret = 0;

  ret = recv(id_client, &size, 4, 0);  //<<< Now I know the length of the string I will get

  if (ret >= 0)
  {
    ret = recv(id_client, buffer, size, 0);
    if (ret >= 0)
    {
      buffer[ret] = '\0';
      std::cout << "Received: " << buffer << std::endl;
    }
  }
  return (ret);
}
```

I don't want to use a fixed buffer and I would like to use the unique_ptr (because it is a good way to respect the RAII)

How could I do that ?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could just use `std::string` instead:

```
std::string buffer;
int size = 0;                                                                                          
int ret = 0;                                                                                           

ret = recv(id_client, &size, 4, 0);
buffer.resize(size);

//later..
recv(id_client, &buffer[0], size, 0);
```

`buffer` will now contain the received data and the correct size. It will also be destroyed for you because of RAII.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer, it works like a charm! I didn't know that std::string was also considered as char*, thank you!

Comment: Btw you were too fast for stackoverflow, I must wait 5 minutes to approve your answer, thank!

Comment: @void `&string[0]` is [only guaranteed to work since C++11](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1986974/7571258) standard. See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33124544/7571258).

Comment: @zett42 And OP asked about a solution with `unique_ptr`, which is C++11 minimally as well.

Comment: Fair enough. I have suggested adding the appropriate tag.

Comment: I'm compiling using -std=c++14, there is no problem for me, thank you very much