# In C++, is a string type object an array of characters just like a C-string object?

Tags: c++, c-strings

So I know that all C-strings are arrays of characters in C++. What about strings?

Also why is `char x[] = {'H', 'i'};` NOT a C-string? 
`x` is an array of characters which means it's a C-string. Am I missing something?

Comment: No, `std::string` is a class. `char x[] = {'H', 'i'};` is not a valid c-string, because there's no terminating `'\0'` character.

Comment: The description of the `c-strings` tag you used: "*A string in the programming language C is represented as a sequence of characters followed by a null terminator (represented as \0).*"

Comment: Are you asking specifically about `std::string`? Because in `C++` you could choose to represent *string type objects* in all sorts of ways.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. But I wanna be clear on this question: Is a string(not C-string) an array of characters in C++?

Answer (score 3):

I just found good explanation for your question here: [C strings and C++ strings](https://www.prismnet.com/~mcmahon/Notes/strings.html). In short:

A C string is usually declared as an array of char. However, an array of char is NOT by itself a C string. A valid C string requires the presence of a terminating "null character" (a character with ASCII value 0, usually represented by the character literal '\0').

A C++ string is an object of the class string, which is defined in the header file  and which is in the standard namespace. The string class has several constructors that may be called (explicitly or implicitly) to create a string object.

Representations in memory:

C-String
[image: C-String]

C++ string
[image: C++ string]

**Updated:**

You should understand that:

1. C++ offers more character types than `char` in C, e.g. UTF-16 and UTF-32.
2. C++ defines a thing called `std::basic_string` that is a class template for making strings out of those character types.
3. C++ `typedef` the class template for `char` type as `std::string`.

Now, you know that `std::string` is the `basic_string` for `char`-typed characters. Referring to [Does std::string need to store its character in a contiguous piece of memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33124479/does-stdstring-need-to-store-its-character-in-a-contiguous-piece-of-memory), if you are mentioning `std::string` then for `C++ 11` and later versions, it is essentially AN array (not TWO or MORE arrays) of `char`-typed characters. For `C++` versions prior to `C++ 11` or for some other types of characters (I am not sure actually), the underlying memory might not be contiguous (i.e. it may need TWO or MORE arrays (not AN array) for storing a string).

Comment: The C++ string representation is not true pre C++ 11 because they weren't guaranteed to be laid out contiguously in memory and for C++ 11 and on, they are guaranteed to be nul terminated.

Comment: so is a C++ string always an 'array of characters'? or is it not necessarily?

Comment: Since "The C++ string representation is not true pre C++ 11 because they weren't guaranteed to be laid out contiguously in memory" then it could be composed of multiple arrays of characters (not necessarily AN array) -- this thing actually varies depending C++ versions and the character type. See more at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33124479/does-stdstring-need-to-store-its-character-in-a-contiguous-piece-of-memory.

Comment: so... I read the answers on that link... couldn't really understand much...because I'm a beginner... but it seems like you're saying that in 'some C++ versions', all strings are 'arrays of characters' while in 'some other C++ versions', strings are NOT arrays of characters. correct?

Comment: @NewLearner Since C++11, the standard guarantees that the pointer returned by the `data()` member of `std::string` points to `size()` characters followed by a `'\0'`. Previously there wasn't such a member, and the member `c_str()` *might* return a copy.

Comment: @Caleth so since C++11, ALL strings(not c-strings) are arrays of characters?

Comment: @NewLearner what do you mean by *are*? There is a required to be something sufficiently `char[]` like *somewhere*, *owned* by the `std::string` instance. Many implementations locate that *within* the `std::string` instance when the size is sufficiently small, but in general it is supplied by a `std::allocator<char>` from the free store

Comment: @NewLearner I added more explanations.

Comment: @duong_dajgja Thank you so much. Just to clarify, since C++ 11 and later, a string type object and a c-string type object are BOTH an array of characters but only the c-string type object has '\0' at the end right?

Answer (score 0):

C string is a ***null terminated string***, so, any character array that doesn't end in zero, is not a C string.

C string is character array `char *` or `char []`

But about the C++ strings, it is a class that has a lot of operations (methods) that can happen on it, it has length and it checks the length (like C++ `vector` and `array`) when you try to access an array subscript of it (using the `at` method). Its copying may be more performant because length to allocate a new memory location is known.

You can create a `std::string` from a C string. There is a constructor that takes a C string and a length and create a std::string from them.

All C functions that handles strings, treat C strings as null terminated, so if it is not, C would keep searching for the nearest next null, which is extremely dangerous.

Comment: "*it checks the length (like C++ `vector` and `array`) when you try to access an array subscribe of it*" - not true. Only `.at()` checks for a valid index.

Answer (score 0):

C++ offers standard library form in which `class string` is defined. Class String is not just a C character string (`char* C` or char sz[]). Class string has methods and attributes  while the latter no. Also class string its size changes runtime while the latter not. It also manage memory for you in its Ctor and dtor. As an advice use Class string as much as possible rather than using char*.

- Class String appends a NULL Character `\0` at the end of the string as a sign of the end of string while the latter no.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the previous answers char x[] = {'H', 'i'}; is not a valid C String as there is no null character to identify the termination or end of string. C++ Standard Template provides class String which guarantees dynamic contiguous memory allocation (similar to Vector) and easy access by index. more on this can be found in https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string.

Comment: contiguous memory from C++ 11.