# Does Visual Studio 2012 (VC11) implement the C++11 guarantee that std::string uses contiguous memory?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, c++11, stdstring

[I've seen a few questions asking this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/760790/is-it-legal-to-write-to-stdstring) from before C++11 started being implemented by compilers. [VS2012 currently implements some C++11 functionality](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx), but has plenty of unimplemented C++11 features. I cannot find mention of whether strings are now guaranteed contiguous or not, and am wondering if they are.

The C++11 guarantee of contiguousness is item 21.4.1.5 of [this working draft of the standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf).

If possible I would like an official citation with the answer.

Comment: I believe 2010 implements it as well. Unless there is a regression, it should be implemented in 2012.

Comment: Do you happen to have any source for that information? I've edited the question to reflect that I'd like a citation (if possible) with the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visual C++ has always used contiguous storage for `std::string`.

One of the design decisions for implementing the contiguity requirement was that all current compilers were doing that anyway.  Microsoft is quite well represented on the ISO C++ committee; there's no chance that they overlooked it.  Visual C++ did go through a phase of implementing a copy-on-write "optimization" but never was one of the ones using non-contiguous "ropes".

Answer (score 0):

I don't know in detail what the standard says, but `std::string` has the very interesting method `c_str()` that returns a `const char*` to the null-terminated string.

I would be crazy to have strings implemented not using contiguous memory. Especially because `c_str()` is also const.

So, applying the Occam's razor, we can say that it should be safe. And it has nothing to do with C++11, it's applicable also to the older standards.