# is there a way to set the length of a std::string without modifying the buffer content?

Tags: c++11, char, stdstring

According to the statements made in the answers of these questions

- [Is writing to &str[0] buffer (of a std:string) well-defined behaviour in C++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25169915)
- [Is it legal to write to std::string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/760790)
- [writing directly to std::string internal buffers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1042940)

.. in C++11 it should be possible to call a C API function which takes a char pointer to store the output like this:

```
str::string str;
str.reserve(SOME_MAX_VALUE);
some_C_API_func(&str[0]);
```

But is there now a legal way to **set the size** of the string to the length of the (null terminated) content inside the buffer? Something like this:

```
str.set_size(strlen(&str[0]));
```

This is a very unaesthetic abuse of `std::string` anyway I hear you say, but I can't create a temporary `char` buffer on stack so I would have to create a buffer in heap and destroy it afterwards (which I want to avoid).

Is there a nice way to do this? Maybe not reserving but *resizing* and calling `erase()` afterwards would do it but it doesn't feel nice neater..

Comment: Have you tried `resize`?

Comment: yes, but `resize()` seems to modify the content. At least when I `reserve()` the buffer and `resize()` it afterwards the string is empty afterwards. It seems to work together with `resize(SOME_MAX_VALUE)`. If someone convinces me that this is the most sophisticated approach I'm happy :)

Comment: @frans , why don't you use std::array to set string size ??

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should be using `resize()` not `reserve()`, then `resize()` again to set the final length.

Otherwise when you `resize()` from zero to the result returned by `strlen()` the array will be filled with zero characters, overwriting what you wrote into it. The string is allowed to do that, because it (correctly) assumes that everything from the current size to the current reserved capacity is uninitialized data that doesn't contain anything.

In order for the string to know that the characters are actually valid and their contents should be preserved, you need to use `resize()` initially, not `reserve()`. Then when you `resize()` again to make the string smaller it only truncates the unwanted end of the string and adds a null terminator, it won't overwrite what you wrote into it.

N.B. the initial `resize()` will zero-fill the string, which is not strictly necessary in your case because you're going to overwrite the portion you care about and then discard the rest anyway. If the strings are very long and profiling shows the zero-filling is a problem then you could do this instead:

```
std::unique_ptr<char[]> str(new char[SOME_MAX_VALUE]);
some_C_API_func(str.get());
```

Comment: The approach with `unique_ptr` doesn't allow to e.g. compare strings using `operator==`.

Answer (score 1):

This was/is a known limitation of C++ until C++20.

From C++23 you can use [`resize_and_overwrite()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/resize_and_overwrite):